# Is this self initialization valid?

Tags: c++, initialization, initialization-order

I have this question, which i thought about earlier, but figured it's not trivial to answer

```
int x = x + 1;
int main() {
  return x;
}
```

My question is whether the behavior of the program is defined or undefined if it's valid at all. If it's defined, is the value of `x` known in `main`?

Comment: Interesting. At least GCC gives 1, even with `-std=c++98 -pedantic`.

Comment: Compiling this with MSVC9 (15.00.30729.01) gives 1.

Comment: Sequence Point comes to mind http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Comment: Why would someone write code like this? If something, this might/will confuse the static analyzer you're using. I would consider the behaviour undefined, even though many compilers give consistent result x=1.

Comment: @Schedler i recommend against such code. It's purely a quiz, without any practical background on my part. :)

Comment: For the [constexpr case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34276373/1708801) it was recently clarified that this is not well defined. It seems to imply that this case is but the changed language still seems vague on this point. I don't know how I missed this question when I was doing my research previously.

Comment: @shafik. I would disagree and it seems your answer does aswell. It seems well defined, but illformed.

Comment: Well this case is not *constant initialization* which is what the defect report is about. I missed this phrase *Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place*. Which should make this well-formed. I don't know why, when I originally read the changes I thought it was unclear for this case.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's defined, and x should have the value 1. §3.6.2/1 says: "Objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place."

After that, I think it's all pretty straightforward.

Comment: Hm, amazing how subtle yet important "before any other initialization takes place." is.

Comment: I wish it was undefined as then we could say don't write stuff like that its hard to work out what you mean without looking it up in the standard.

Comment: @Martin York: I, for one, have no problem at all with saying "don't do that", about code like this (and quite a few other things that have defined behavior).

Answer (score 11):

> My question is whether the behavior of the program is defined or undefined if it's valid at all. If it's defined, is the value of x known in main?

This code is definitely not clean, but to me it should work predictably.

`int x` puts the variable into the data segment which is defined to be zero at the program start. Before `main()`, static initializers are called. For `x` that is the code `x = x + 1`. `x = 0 + 1 = 1`. Thus the main() would return 1.

The code would definitely work in unpredictable fashion if `x` is a local variable, allocated on stack. State of stack, unlike the data segment, is pretty much guaranteed to contain undefined garbage.

Answer (score 6):

The 'x' variable in stored in the .bss, which is filled with 0s when you load the program. Consequently, the value of 'x' is 0 when the program gets loaded in memory.

Then before main is called, "x = x + 1" is executed.

I don't know if it's valid or not, but the behavior is not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Before the main call x must be initialized to 0 therefore it's value must be 1 one you enter main, and you will return 1. It's a defined behavior.