# what is wrong with this program?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, io

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string x;
    getline(cin,x);
    ofstream o("f:/demo.txt");
    o.write( (char*)&x , sizeof(x) );
}
```

I get the unexpected output.I don't get what i write in a string function.
Why is this ?
Please explain .

**Like when i write `steve pro` i get the output as `8/ steve pro ÌÌÌÌÌÌ          ÌÌÌÌ` in the file**

I expect that the output be **steve pro**

Comment: What unexpected output? Why didn't you tell us what output you got?

Comment: Who on earth voted to close as "not a real question"?

Comment: There is no badge for closing questions. I don't understand what creates trigger-happy close voters.

Comment: @Tomalak - the question was edited to give more information, that close vote was likely before that edit.

Comment: @Dominic: When I answered this question, three minutes after it was posted, it had more than enough information to answer and no close vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are treating an `std::string` like something that it is not. It's a complex object that, somewhere in its internals, stores characters for you.

There is no reason to assume that a character array is at the start of the object (`&x`), and the `sizeof` the object has no relation to how many characters it may indirectly hold/represent.

You're probably looking for:

```
o.write(x.c_str(), x.length());
```

Or just use the built-in formatted I/O mechanism:

```
o << x;
```

Comment: yes ! i was looking for `o.write(x.c_str(), x.length());` . **but what is `c_str` and why i can't use `sizeof(x)` ?**

Comment: @steve: `.c_str()` is the member function of `std::string` that gives you a `char const*` to use with C-style APIs (and with things like iostream `.write`). You can't just randomly cast complex objects to `char*` -- you have to obtain an actual pointer to a valid buffer; the `std::string` documentation explains this. And `sizeof` is _not_ the length of the string, but the size of the physical `std::string` object. | I'm still sure that you're actually looking for `o << x`; don't ignore it just because you haven't seen it before. Proper usage of streams should be covered in your C++ book.

Comment: @ Tomalak Geret'kal Which is better to use **`o.write(x.c_str(), x.length());`**    or    **`o << x;`** ?

Comment: @steve, `o << x` is better because it's less error prone, readable and more `C++` style !

Comment: @steve: Neither is "better". The former is "unformatted I/O", and thus suitable for writing binary data. The latter is "formatted I/O", designed for easy, concise output of text data. You have text data, so that's what I'd recommend for use.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have an incorrect model of `sizeof`, so let me try to get it right.

For any given object `x` of type `T`, the expression `sizeof(x)` is a compile-time constant. C++ will never actually inspect the object `x` at runtime. The compiler knows that `x` is of type `T`, so you can imagine it silently transforming `sizeof(x)` to `sizeof(T)`, if you will.

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "hello";
    std::string b = "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it.";
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl;   // this prints 4 on my system
    std::cout << sizeof(b) << std::endl;   // this also prints 4 on my system
}
```

All C++ objects of the same type take up the exact amount of memory. Of course, since strings have vastly different lengths, they will internally store a pointer to a heap-allocated block of memory. But this does not concern `sizeof`. It couldn't, because as I said, `sizeof` operates at compile-time.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. what do you mean by `The compiler knows that x is of type T, so you can imagine it silently transforming sizeof(x) to sizeof(T)`

Comment: @steve: It means the value that `sizeof` returns for an object is the same as the value the `sizeof` would return for a type of that object.

Answer (score 2):

You get exactly what you write: the binary raw value of a pointer to char...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;
    getline(cin,x);
    ofstream o("tester.txt");
    o << x;
    o.close();
}
```

If you insist on writing a buffer directly, you can use

```
o.write(x.c_str(), x.size());
```

**PS** A little attention to code formatting unclouds the mind

Comment: Is there any good reason for explicitly calling `o.close();` at the end?

Comment: No, he wouldn't have gotten the value of a pointer (`o.write` is not formatted output). He would have gotten garbage though, due to printing the first `sizeof(std::string)` bytes of a complex object.

Comment: @Tomalak: Didn't I say _binary_?

Comment: @sehe: Irrelevant. He's not getting _any_ "raw value of a pointer" in his output.

Comment: @sehe: no, `write` takes a pointer to the data to be written. `(char*)&x` is a pointer to the first byte of the storage representation of `x`. `char` is a legal type to alias and inspect any object. There's no UB here, it's just that the bytes of a `string` object aren't terribly interesting when printed (beyond proving that in this case a small-string optimization is in effect).

Comment: Sorry, the part where I got mixed up was that sizeof(x) doesn't -- of course -- return sizeof(char*); Oh well; it's not very bad to get confused explaining broken code, isn't it :)

Comment: @Steve: Indeed, it's a good demonstration of the small-string optimization!

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the object's address to write into the file, whereas the original content lies somewhere else, pointed to by one of its internal pointers.

Try this:

```
string x;
getline(cin,x);
ofstream o("D:/tester.txt");
o << x;
// or
// o.write( x.c_str() , x.length());
```