# String class e char in C++

Tags: c++

When I have

```
char anything[20];
cout << sizeof anything;
```

it prints 20.

However

```
string anymore;
cout << sizeof anymore; // it prints 4
getline(cin, anymore); // let's suppose I type more than one hundred characters
cout << sizeof anymore; // it still prints 4 !
```

I would like to understand how c++ manages this. Thanks

Comment: to get the length type anymore.length()

Comment: [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533041/what-is-wrong-with-this-program/6533698#6533698)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` is a compile-time construct.  It has nothing to do with runtime, but rather gives a fixed result based on the type passed to it (or the type of the value passed to it).  So char[20] is 20 bytes, but a string might be 4 or 8 bytes or whatever depending on the implementation.  The sizeof isn't telling you how much storage the string allocated dynamically to hold its contents.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is a *compile-time* operator.  It tells you the size of the *type*.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of anything - is array with 20 characters. Sizeof of each character 1 byte - so, totally 20 bytes.
And string class contain pointer for the begin of char-array and size_t(unsigned int for example) - it's 4 bytes. sizeof doesn't know how many memory you allocated for the string, it know just that you have pointer for something, because it's compile-time function.

Comment: It's implementation-defined as to what `std::string` actually contains.

Comment: I think that you should make that clear in your answer. At present, your answer seems to state that `std::string` itself, as defined by C++, always, will contain a pointer and a `size_t`, which is a guarantee that simply does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` isn't what you have decided that it should be. It doesn't magically perceive the semantics of whatever type you throw at it. All it knows is how many bytes are used up, *directly* for storing the instance of a type.

For an array of five characters, that's 5. For a pointer (to anything, including an array), that's usually 4 or 8. For an `std::string`, it's however many bytes your C++ Standard Library implementation happens to need to do its work. This work usually involves dynamic allocation, so the four bytes you're looking likely represent just enough storage for a pointer.

It is not to be confused with specific "size" semantics. For `std::string`, that's `anymore.length()`, which uses whatever internal magic is required to calculate the length of the buffer of characters that it's stored *somewhere*, possibly (and usually) indirectly.

For what it's worth, I'm *very* surprised that a `std::string` could take up only four bytes. I'd expect it'd store *at least* "length" and a pointer, which is usually going to take more than four bytes.

Comment: it's a class type, so the length is probably a property. (?)

Comment: @Martin: Huh? It still has to be stored somewhere buddy.

Comment: It's possible, I suppose, that the length is stored in the first few bytes of the allocated buffer... but I can't imagine why. You'd gain efficiency for move and copy operations, but lose efficiency for anything that had to actually _use_ that length value, which is pretty much everything `std::string` does.

Answer (score -3):

The 'string' type is a class template.  String instances are accessed by references, AKA pointers.  4 bytes on 32-bit systems.

Comment: References are not "aka" pointers. And neither have anything to do with this. And `std::string` is a type, a template _instance_. It is not a template type.