# Lvalue to Rvalue conversions

Tags: c++, lvalue-to-rvalue

From 4.1/2

> The value contained in the object indicated by the lvalue is the
>   rvalue result. When an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion occurs within the
>   operand of sizeof (5.3.3) the value contained in the referenced object
>   is not accessed, since that operator does not evaluate its operand.

Out of curiosity, I was wondering, does the same applies to the if, for, while statements, i.e lvalue is converted to rvalue when the result of statement is evaluated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Without `lvalue-to-rvalue` conversion, it cannot read it's *value*.

Loosely speaking, think of *lvalue* as some sort of container, and *rvalue* as the value contained in the container.

C++03, section §3.10/7 reads,

> Whenever an lvalue appears in a context where an rvalue is expected, the lvalue is converted to an rvalue; see 4.1, 4.2, and 4.3.

Read it along with, §4.1/2 (your quotation),

> The value contained in the object indicated by the lvalue is the rvalue result.

Related topic:

- [What standard clause mandates this lvalue-to-rvalue conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376580/what-standard-clause-mandates-this-lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion)

Comment: In terms of standard, Does it mean that it 'lexically contains an rvalue'?. I remember reading it but i'm not sure if i'm getting it right.

Comment: @parc84: Added quotation from the spec.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes.

When a bool rvalue is expected, the conversion also is applied. Let test be a variable to see an example:

```
if( test )
```

Rvalue of test, true or false, is evaluated inside the if.