# When does lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happen, how does it work, and can it fail?

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion, lvalue-to-rvalue

I see the term "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion" used in many places throughout the C++ standard. This kind of conversion is often done implicitly, as far as I can tell.

One unexpected (to me) feature of the phrasing from the standard is that they decide to treat lvalue-to-rvalue as a conversion. What if they had said that a glvalue is always acceptable instead of a prvalue? Would that phrase actually have a different meaning? For example, we read that lvalues and xvalues are examples of glvalues. We don't read that lvalues and xvalues are convertible to glvalues. Is there a difference in meaning?

Before my first encounter with this terminology, I used to model lvalues and rvalues mentally more or less as follows:

> lvalues are *always* able to act as rvalues, but in addition can appear on the left side of an `=`, and to the right of an `&`.

This, to me, is the intuitive behavior that if I have a variable name, then I can put that name everywhere where I would have put a literal. This model seems consistent with lvalue-to-rvalue implicit conversions terminology used in the standard, as long as this implicit conversion is guaranteed to happen.

But, because they use this terminology, I started wondering whether the implicit lvalue-to-rvalue conversion may fail to happen in some cases. That is, maybe my mental model is wrong here. Here is the relevant wording in [[basic.lval] p6](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#6) (thanks to the commenters):

> Whenever a glvalue appears as an operand of an operator that requires a prvalue for that operand, the lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer standard conversions are applied to convert the expression to a prvalue.
>
> [*Note*: An attempt to bind an rvalue reference to an lvalue is not such a context; see [[dcl.init.ref]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref).
> — *end note*]

I understand what they describe in the note is the following:

```
int x = 1;
int && y = x; //in this declaration context, x won't bind to y.
// but the literal 1 would have bound, so this is one context where the implicit 
// lvalue to rvalue conversion did not happen.  
// The expression on right is an lvalue. if it had been a prvalue, it would have bound.
// Therefore, the lvalue to prvalue conversion did not happen (which is good).
```

So, my question is (are):

1. Could someone clarify the contexts where this conversion can happen implicitly? Specifically, other than the context of binding to an rvalue reference, are there any other where lvalue-to-rvalue conversions fail to happen implicitly?
2. I rvalue-reference binding is not a context where we expect a prvalue expression (on the right)?
3. Like other conversions, does the glvalue-to-prvalue conversion involve work at runtime that would allow me to observe it?

My aim here is not to ask if it is desirable to allow such a conversion. I'm trying to learn to explain to myself the behavior of this code using the standard as starting point.

---

A good answer would go through the quote I placed above and explain (based on parsing the text) whether the note in it is also implicit from its text. It would then maybe add any other quotes that let me know the other contexts in which this conversion may fail to happen implicitly, or explain there are no more such contexts.  Perhaps a general discussion of why glvalue to prvalue is considered a conversion.

Comment: Note that `int && y = x;` isn't an expression itself, but a declaration. Therefore, lvalue-to-rvalue conversion isn't automatically applied to the "operand on the right side of `=`".

Comment: That's not lvalue-to-rvalue conversion failing; that's rvalue reference binding failing.

Comment: Also note that lvalues can still "act as" (can be converted to) rvalues, even for rvalue-reference-binding. You just have to apply the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion manually; as I said, it isn't applied automatically for reference binding: `int x = 42; int && y = +x;` (the unary `+` invokes lvalue-to-rvalue conversion) -- this however doesn't bind `y` to `x`, but to a temporary, as it had for `int && y = 42;`.

Comment: @DyP: well, there's still an expression on the right... But I think the standard actually says, "when an rvalue is expected; binding to a reference is *not* such a situation".

Comment: @KerrekSB I fail to find where it says that :( I can only find that the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happens for glvalue-operands of *operators* that expect an rvalue.

Comment: @DyP: 3.10/2 I think.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks! Well that is interesting. Sounds to me like that should be more of a note than actual normative text o.O

Comment: @DyP: It **is** a note :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB No I meant the whole paragraph.

Comment: @DyP @Lightness, thanks for the clarification about this context being a declaration. 
What I mean is, if I had used the literal `1`, it would have worked. Other than a reference declaration, is there any place where we cannot replace a constant, with an lvalue, and have the code still work? In the above context, we cannot do that (we can use `std::move()`, as you say, but I realize now that I am interested in the failure of implicit lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (I've amended the question)).

Comment: @orm is [this Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf) any help? In particular, section **3.10** gives a nice introduction to different flavours of lvalue and rvalue. **4.1** to **4.3** discuss conversions and **5**, particularly **5.0.6** on page 83 about conversions via xvalue... If that's helpful I can write it up as an 'answer', but I'm not sure whether it's quite what you're after...

Comment: @GnomeDePlume Rather refer to [_this_ Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), which is the closest to the actual C++11 Standard (publicly available, at least; the absolute closest is N3291 but not publicly available; but the only [changes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3338.html) between N3291 and N3337 are editorial (mainly typo fixes))

Comment: Hey @GnomeDePlume.  I think a satisfying answer would be to clarify the clause in the question "Whenever a.." For example, that note above explains that binding a reference is not such a context. Is this a note because it is implicit already? if it is implicit, what is the reasoning?   Is this exhaustive? or are there other similar contexts where it is implicit.

Comment: By "that note above" i mean the note within the cited clause: "...Note: An attempt to bind an rvalue reference to an lvalue is not such a context; see 8.5.3 .—end note". When binding to a reference, is the problem that this is not a context "where a prvalue is expected"? In that case, what is expected?

Comment: @orm An xvalue is expected. When you initialize an rvalue reference with prvalue, it actually binds to a temporary xvalue initialized with that prvalue. In other words, `int && x = 1; ++x;` doesn't actually change the value of `1`. But `int y = 42; int &&x = std::move(y); ++x;` will change the value of `y`.

Comment: Do you think thats the reason why the conversion to prvalue is not automatic? Since whats expected is not exclusively a prvalue, but an xvalue or prvalue? We can make that an answer perhaps. Lets see what people say.

Comment: @orm I'd find that surprising if an lvalue could be bound to an rvalue reference as you'd bind a copy of the object you name. If there was a conversion to prvalue, `int x; int&& r = x;` would bind `r` to a temporary/copy of `x`. If it wouldn't bind a temporary but `x` directly, that would be dangerous, as rvalue references conventionally imply that you can steal the resources of the objects they refer to.

Comment: @DyP, thanks for your comment. I would also find it surprising, also undesirable because then it seems rvalue references would bind to anything, perhaps altering overload resolution in some cases.  And implying this binding will  either create a temporary or allow dangerously modifying objects. Rather than explain that it is undesirable, I'm trying to explain the behavior in terms of the standard.

Comment: So you (just) want to have quotes?

Comment: Yeah, that would be good.  Or analogies from other parts of the standard. I'm trying to learn to read it.

Comment: One unexpected (to me) feature of the phrasing from the standard is that they decide to treat lvalue-to-rvalue as a conversion. What if they had said that a glvalue is always acceptable instead of a prvalue.  Would that phrase actually have a different meaning?  For example, we read that lvalues and xvalues are examples of glvalues. We don't read that lvalues and xvalues are convertible to glvalues. Why the difference. Maybe I'm reading too much into this.

Comment: @DyP quotes are good.  I'd like to see a more experienced programmer run through the quotes and explain how they interpret them.

Comment: @Casey: do you have a particular reference explaining an xvalue is expected? this would answer my question.

Comment: @orm Section 4.0.3 on page 77 of gx_'s link has some interesting points. "The eﬀect of either implicit conversion is the same as performing the declaration and initialization and then using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion. The
result is an lvalue if T is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type (8.3.2), an xvalue
if T is an rvalue reference to object type, and a prvalue otherwise. The expression e is used as a glvalue if
and only if the initialization uses it as a glvalue". (Check out the full paragraph.) The conversion hierarchy is interesting.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is more than just *use an lvalue where an rvalue is required*. It can create a copy of a class, and always yields a *value*, not an object.

I'm using n3485 for "C++11" and n1256 for "C99".

---

### Objects and values

The most concise description is in C99/3.14:

> **object**
>
> region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent
>   values

There's also a bit in C++11/[intro.object]/1

> Some objects are *polymorphic*; the implementation generates information associated with
>   each such object that makes it possible to determine that object’s type during program execution. For other objects, the interpretation of the values found therein is determined by the type of the expressions used to access them.

So an object contains a value (can contain).

---

### Value categories

Despite its name, *value categories* classify expressions, not values. lvalue-expressions even *cannot* be considered values.

The full taxonomy / categorization can be found in [basic.lval]; [here's a StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3601602/420683).

Here are the parts about objects:

> - An *lvalue* ([...]) designates a function or an object. [...]
> - An *xvalue* (an “eXpiring” value) also refers to an object [...]
> - A *glvalue* (“generalized” lvalue) is an lvalue or an xvalue.
> - An *rvalue* ([...]) is an xvalue, a temporary object or subobject thereof, or a value that is not associated with an object.
> - A prvalue (“pure” rvalue) is an rvalue that is not an xvalue. [...]

Note the phrase "a value that is not associated with an object". Also note that as xvalue-expressions refer to objects, true *values* must always occur as prvalue-expressions.

---

### The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion

As footnote 53 indicates, it should now be called "glvalue-to-prvalue conversion". First, here's the quote:

> 1    A glvalue of a non-function, non-array type `T` can be converted to a prvalue. If `T` is an incomplete type, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. If the object to which the glvalue refers is not an object of type `T` and is not an object of a type derived from `T`, or if the object is uninitialized, a program
>   that necessitates this conversion has undefined behavior. If `T` is a non-class type, the type of the prvalue is the cv-unqualified version of `T`. Otherwise, the type of the prvalue is `T`.

This first paragraph specifies the requirements and the resulting type of the conversion. It isn't yet concerned with the *effects* of the conversion (other than Undefined Behaviour).

> 2    When an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion occurs in an unevaluated operand or a subexpression thereof the value contained in the referenced object is not accessed. Otherwise, if the glvalue has a class type, the conversion copy-initializes a temporary of type `T` from the glvalue and the result of the conversion is a prvalue for the temporary. Otherwise, if the glvalue has (possibly cv-qualified) type `std::nullptr_t`, the
>   prvalue result is a null pointer constant. Otherwise, the value contained in the object indicated by the glvalue is the prvalue result.

I'd argue that you'll see the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion most often applied to non-class types. For example,

```
struct my_class { int m; };

my_class x{42};
my_class y{0};

x = y;
```

The expression `x = y` does *not* apply the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `y` (that would create a temporary `my_class`, by the way). The reason is that `x = y` is interpreted as `x.operator=(y)`, which takes `y` per default *by reference*, not *by value* (for reference binding, see below; it cannot bind an rvalue, as that would be a temporary object different from `y`). However, the default definition of `my_class::operator=` does apply the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x.m`.

Therefore, the most important part to me seems to be

> Otherwise, the value contained in the object indicated by the glvalue is the prvalue result.

So typically, an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion will just *read the value from an object*. It isn't just a no-op conversion between value (expression) categories; it can even create a temporary by calling a copy constructor. And the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion always returns a prvalue *value*, not a (temporary) *object*.

Note that the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not the only conversion that converts an lvalue to a prvalue: There's also the array-to-pointer conversion and the function-to-pointer conversion.

---

### values and expressions

Most expressions don't yield objects<sup>[[citation needed]]</sup>. However, an *id-expression* can be an *identifier*, which denotes an *entity*. An object is an entity, so there are expressions which yield objects:

```
int x;
x = 5;
```

The left hand side of the *assignment-expression* `x = 5` also needs to be an expression. `x` here is an *id-expression*, because `x` is an identifier. The result of this *id-expression* is *the object denoted by `x`*.

Expressions apply implicit conversions: [expr]/9

> Whenever a glvalue expression appears as an operand of an operator that expects a prvalue for that operand, the lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer standard conversions are applied to convert the expression to a prvalue.

And /10 about *usual arithmetic conversions* as well as /3 about user-defined conversions.

I'd love now to quote an operator that "expects a prvalue for that operand", but cannot find any but casts. For example, [expr.dynamic.cast]/2 "If `T` is a pointer type, `v` [the operand] shall be a prvalue of a pointer to complete class type".

The *usual arithmetic conversions* required by many arithmetic operators do invoke an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion indirectly via the standard conversion used. All standard conversions but the three that convert from lvalues to rvalues expect prvalues.

The simple assignment however doesn't invoke the usual arithmetic conversions. It is defined in [expr.ass]/2 as:

> In simple assignment (`=`), the value of the expression replaces that of the object referred to by the left operand.

So although it doesn't explicitly require a prvalue expression on the right hand side, it does require a *value*. It is not clear to me if this *strictly* requires the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. There's an argument that accessing the value of an uninitialized variable should always invoke undefined behaviour (also see [CWG 616](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#616)), no matter if it's by assigning its value to an object or by adding its value to another value. But this undefined behaviour is only required for an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (AFAIK), which then should be the only way to access the value stored in an object.

If this more conceptual view is valid, that we need the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to access the value inside an object, then it'd be much easier to understand where it is (and needs to be) applied.

---

### Initialization

As with simple assignment, there's a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6376580/420683) whether or not the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is required to initialize another object:

```
int x = 42; // initializer is a non-string literal -> prvalue
int y = x;  // initializer is an object / lvalue
```

For fundamental types, [dcl.init]/17 last bullet point says:

> Otherwise, the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the initializer expression. Standard conversions will be used, if necessary, to convert the initializer expression to the cv-unqualified version of the destination type; no user-defined conversions are considered. If the conversion cannot be done, the initialization is ill-formed.

However, it also mentioned the *value of the initializer expression*. Similar to the simple-assignment-expression, we can take this as an indirect invocation of the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

---

### Reference binding

If we see lvalue-to-rvalue conversion as a way to access the value of an object (plus the creation of a temporary for class type operands), we understand that it's *not* applied generally for binding to a reference: A reference is an lvalue, it always refers to an object. So if we bound values to references, we'd need to create temporary objects holding those values. And this is indeed the case if the initializer-expression of a reference is a prvalue (which is a value or a temporary object):

```
int const& lr = 42; // create a temporary object, bind it to `r`
int&& rv = 42;      // same
```

Binding a prvalue to an lvalue reference is prohibited, but prvalues of class types with conversion functions that yield lvalue references may be bound to lvalue references of the converted type.

The complete description of reference binding in [dcl.init.ref] is rather long and rather off-topic. I think the essence of it relating to this question is that references refer to objects, therefore no glvalue-to-prvalue (object-to-value) conversion.

Comment: As pointer arithmetics are not subject to the usual arithmetic conversions, there's also no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied explicitly to pointers as operands (even though their value is used).

Comment: It might need a TL;DR

Comment: +1 this is very detailed. I don't see indirection covered here, as far as I can tell indirection does not cause an `lvalue to revalue` conversion but it is not obvious.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Indirection using unary `*` yields an lvalue, [expr.unary.op]/1

Comment: That is what I think as well but I have seen this justification used several times to indicate something is undefined behavior like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4286034/1708801) but I don't see that it applies. I guess the opinion is that any read of a value is an `lvalue-to-rvalue conversion` which seems too broad.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Ah, you mean an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied to the *pointer* (I was referring to the lvalue resulting from indirection). Yes, it seems no l-t-r conversion is mandated directly here. Even the word *value* doesn't appear in [expr.unary.op]/1. (That also seems to be the case for pointer arithmetic, as mentioned in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850536/lvalue-to-rvalue-implicit-conversion/20999389#comment31558031_20999389).)

Comment: Regarding "a value, not an object."  , the C++ standard continually uses the term "object" to describe temporaries of class type, which are associated with prvalues

Comment: @M.M I'm not sure if this answer is salvageable, after the changes to the definition of *object* I don't really know what's going on in the Standard right now. Also, the l-to-r conversion lost its meaning as the introducer of UB when reading from uninitialized stuff (memory, variables, ...). But I guess you're right, a prvalue of class type is probably an object.

Comment: Can you give an example of a situation in which lvalue-to-rvalue conversion would create a copy / call a copy constructor?

Comment: @JMC Hm, that is not as easy as it might appear: triggering the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on _class_ types is usually conflated with initialization or assigment. Alas, one could argue that `static_cast` would fit, and it does indeed call a constructor on a trivial conversion: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/so7jboosM (`static_cast<T>` explicitly applies the l-t-r conversion to its operand).

Comment: I find this wording strange: an operator that "expects a prvalue for that operand". In C++ you can hardly say that a function _expects_ a certain value category. You can specify only the parameter types in the function signature. In this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/oaobTWMsG) I passed all value categories (l, x, pr) to all types (`T`, `T&`, `T&&`, `const T`, `const T&`, `const T&&`). IMHO `dynamic_cast` actually expects a pointer, and at the call site the argument's value category is irrelevant. No need to talk about l-to-r conversion.

Comment: @Dr.Gut in the terminology of the C++ Standard, an operator is not a function. `dynamic_cast` is also not a function, even if it looks like one. Since value categories and lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applies to _expressions_ we really have to look at the language from a compiler's point of view. You can see this e.g. in clang's AST dump: https://godbolt.org/z/vGP1hfoM5 look at the ImplicitCastExpr which is an LValueToRvalue (conversion).

Comment: @JMC I think passing a `string` variable to a `void SetName(string name);` function can count as example of an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion creating a copy?

Answer (score 5):

On glvalues: A glvalue ("generalized" lvalue) is an expression that is either an lvalue or an xvalue.
A glvalue may be implicitly converted to prvalue with lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer implicit conversion.

Lvalue transformations are applied when lvalue argument (e.g. reference to an object) is used in context where rvalue (e.g. a number) is expected.

**Lvalue to rvalue conversion**
A glvalue of any non-function, non-array type `T` can be implicitly converted to prvalue **of the same type**. If `T` is a non-class type, this conversion also removes cv-qualifiers. Unless encountered in unevaluated context (in an operand of sizeof, typeid, noexcept, or decltype), this conversion effectively copy-constructs a temporary object of type `T` using the original glvalue as the constructor argument, and that temporary object is returned as a prvalue. If the glvalue has the type `std::nullptr_t`, the resulting prvalue is the null pointer constant `nullptr`.

Comment: **1st.** How do you _expect_ an rvalue (e.g. a number) in C++? When declaring a function you can only specify the parameter types. I pretty much think that all functions can accept expressions of all value categories ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/oaobTWMsG)). **2nd.** Is there an example where an lvalue argument is passed to a function, but the lvalue is not good enough, so the compiler copy-constructs a prvalue of the same type to pass it to the function? Sounds weird.

Comment: @Dr.Gut If you have `string myName;` and `void SetName(string name);`, `SetName(myName)` would create a temporary `string` from `myName` and pass the temporary to `SetName`.

Comment: Naturally. But I think they don't call this lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Before you dive into the details, you should know that *lvalue-to-rvalue conversion* means a *read from memory*.

As such, it can fail at runtime, if the lvalue is *invalid* (reference formed from an invalid pointer, dangling reference whose target object has gone out of scope, etc) or the result is *uninitialized*.

Now, compiler optimizations might reorder the actual memory read, combine multiple reads by caching the value in a CPU register, etc.  But the meaning is always a fetch of the object's existing value.

You get undefined behavior if a hypothetical memory read would not succeed, even if the optimizer has transformed the code to avoid actually doing a memory read.  The possible reordering / speculative reads are one of the sources of "time-travel undefined behavior", where a code path that will reach a fetch from an invalid lvalue starts acting weird earlier.