# Does a Comparison Between an Lvalue and a Literal Invoke an Lvalue-to-Rvalue Conversion?

Tags: c++, comparison, rvalue, lvalue, lvalue-to-rvalue

I asked this question: [static_assert of const Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46961749/2642059)

And apparently it comes down to the question does a floating point lvalue get converted to an rvalue for the purposes of comparison?

So in this code does an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion occur?

```
const float foo = 13.0F;
static_assert(foo > 0.0F, "foo must be greater than 0.");
```

Comment: `foo` is a `float`. `0.0` is a `double`. There *has to be* a conversion in order to compare the two since the original types don't match.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks, I made a copy paste error. I've corrected it. I'm asking about the case where the literal is of the same type of the lvalue.

Comment: To whom it may concern this seems to be the sticking point of the "values and expressions" section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20999389/2642059)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is performed. Basically, it's all because `3.0 > 1.2` is a well-formed expression, that contains nothing but prvalues for operands.

First, [[expr]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#9) states (emphasis mine) that

> Whenever a glvalue expression **appears as an operand of an operator
>   that expects a prvalue for that operand**, the lvalue-to-rvalue,
>   array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer standard conversions are
>   applied to convert the expression to a prvalue.

So the question really boils down to *"Do the relational operators **expect** prvalues for operands"*? And the answer to that is also yes. For we need to consider [[expr.rel]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.rel#1):

> ```
> relational-expression:
>   shift-expression
>   relational-expression < shift-expression
>   relational-expression > shift-expression
>   relational-expression <= shift-expression
>   relational-expression >= shift-expression
> ```
>
> The operands shall have arithmetic, enumeration, or pointer type. The
>   operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than or equal to),
>   and >= (greater than or equal to) all yield false or true. The type of
>   the result is bool.

The above grammar production is the important bit. We can follow it (I won't do it entirely here) and reduce `shift-expression` to a `primary-expression`. And one of the productions of a `primary-expression` is a `literal`. For which it is said in [[expr.prim.literal]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.literal):

> A literal is a primary expression. Its type depends on its form. A
>   string literal is an lvalue; all other literals are prvalues.

And *because* most literals are prvalues, I think it's safe to say the relational operators *expect* prvalues for operands.

Comment: This is a great answer, but man if I don't struggle with glvalues and prvalues. I have to look them up every time I read them. rvalues and lvalues are familiar and safe to me since they've been around for basically the entire time I've been a C++ programmer... But... Do you have a heuristic or something that you use to help think about glvalues and prvalues?

Comment: @JonathanMee - I think it's safe to say that a prvalue is very much like what C considers an rvalue. I.e. anything that isn't assignable. A "pure value", possibly without an object to back it up. A glvalue is just anything you can assign to (assuming it isn't const). So any object you can name, either by an actual name, or a reference (lvalue or rvalue ref) to it. Barring UB, a reference always involves the referred to object occupying storage. But like all heuristics, it fails me often enough, even though I can get by with it while working day to day.