# Is the right operand of an assignment always converted to an rvalue?

Tags: c++, lvalue-to-rvalue

I would like a clarification about this particular case:

```
class Test
{
    Test& operator=(const Test& copy)
    {
      ...
    }

    Test() = default;
}

Test a;
Test b;
b = a; //Is "a" converted to an rvalue?
```

"a" is an lvalue, however it is now the righthand operand of the assignment. Does it mean it gets converted to an rvalue?

This code doesn't compile:

```
class Test
{
    Test& operator=(Test&& copy) 
    {
      ...
    }

    Test() = default;
}

Test a;
Test b;
a = b; //Error
```

But this one does:

```
class Test
{
    Test& operator=(Test& copy) 
    {
      ...
    }

    Test() = default;
}

Test a;
Test b;
a = b; //OK
```

Since an lvalue reference cannot bind to an rvalue, does it mean a conversion is not happening here? If that is the case, when does an implicit lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happen? (Other than the case of the operator+ with primitive types)

Comment: `Test b = a;` is not an assignment, but an initialization. It doesn't use `operator=`, but a constructor. And no, there's no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in your example.

Comment: Implicit lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happens whenever an lvalue is used in a context where rvalue is required. A copy constructor cannot be such a context - for a class type, lvalue-to-rvalue conversion implies copying, so if copy constructor required such a conversion, you'd have an infinite recursion.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry, you are right, I've corrected the question. This case applies to both assignments and initializations.

Comment: You can [look at the AST](https://godbolt.org/g/QXzybf) to see how the compiler interprets this. It shows the lvalue going into the constructor directly.

Comment: @wally Thank you, so no conversion is happening at all in this context. Could you give me a simple example where such a conversion with classes is required, causing a copy?

Comment: Are you actually asking whether the right-hand argument to an assignment operator is always an rvalue _just because it's on the right_? Or something else?

Comment: @Useless Yes, that's the main point of the question. However as wally pointed out in this case there is no conversion so I guess the answer is "no". At the end I also ask in which case an implicit lvalue-to-rvalue conversion with non primitive types (classes) happens. An example code would be useful.

Comment: There is an [extensive answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20999389/1460794) dealing with lvalue to rvalue conversions. It specifically shows and explains the `x = y;` case.

Comment: `void f(Test t) {} Test a; f(a);` The function call here would require an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, since the function takes its parameter by value.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm not sure why, but it does not seem to require the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion [here](https://godbolt.org/g/BAfows). I've posted a new question about this to understand better.

Comment: @wally Print something in the copy-constructor. Yours is a no-op, and the compiler is smart enough to optimize the call away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "a" is an lvalue, however it is now the righthand operand of the assignment. Does it mean it gets converted to an rvalue?

In short, yes.     In all versions and drafts of the C++ standard, one of the standard conversions is called the "lvalue-to-rvalue" conversion.

That is applied in the first case you describe.

> Since an lvalue reference cannot bind to an rvalue, does it mean a conversion is not happening here? If that is the case, when does an implicit lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happen? (Other than the case of the operator+ with primitive types)

In the second case, you have declared/defined an `operator=(Test &&)` that accepts an rvalue reference, which suppresses generation of an `operator=(const Test &)`.   In C++11 and later, declaring a `operator=(Test &&)` without one of `operator=(Test &)` or `operator(const Test &)` prevents using an lvalue on the right hand side  (as in your example, `a = b`).

Which does, indirectly, mean a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not employed in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One doubt thought. If conversion is happening in the first case, that should imply a copy in a temporary object for classes, which however doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: I have to admit, I don't understand this myself. [Here](https://godbolt.org/g/MYpQU6) I was able get clang to admit to an lvalue to rvalue conversion. But I could not see the conversion in the AST for any of the other examples.

Comment: It CAN mean creating a temporary object - for example, if you pass `Test` to a function by value.      If the conversion is producing a reference to a named object, however, it doesn't (necessarily) need to create a temporary.

Comment: @wally I find the standard to be very confusing about this implicit conversion. However I believe in the example Igor gave "Test t" is an lvalue too, so no conversion is needed (Just a copy). However in your example the return value of a function is a prvalue and so clang is doing the conversion (copy + conversion).

Comment: @A.S. Ok that makes sense. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50025424/1460794) is a bit more clarification.

Comment: Why would lvalue-to-rvalue happen when binding a reference parameter to the operand?

Answer (score 2):

This is lvalue, `b = a;` calls copy operator

```
class Test
{
    Test& operator=(const Test& copy)
    {
      ...
    }

    Test() = default;
}

Test a;
Test b;
b = a; //Is "a" converted to an rvalue?
```

Error, because your copy constructor and copy operator wasn't generated by compiler, because of declaring move operator

```
class Test
{
    Test& operator=(Test&& copy) 
    {
      ...
    }

    Test() = default;
}

Test a;
Test b;
a = b; //Error
```

If you want to get rvalue you can write this:

```
Test a;
Test b;
a = Test(); //Uses move operator
```

Comment: might want to throw in that calling `std::move()` does do the conversion though.

Answer (score 2):

There is no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in your case (ignoring codes in the definiton of `operator=`).

Here you are using overloaded operators and according to [[expr.pre]/2](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr#pre-2.sentence-3),

> Overloaded operators obey the rules for syntax and evaluation order specified in [expr.compound], but the requirements of operand type and **value category** are replaced by the rules for function call.

So it does not require the right operand to be a prvalue, thus no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.