# Why do lvalue-to-rvalue conversions exist? Why are they required?

Tags: c++

From what I gather, lvalue-to-rvalue conversions happen when an objects value is required, rather than just it's address. Does that mean that lvalues can only hold the address of an object, while a prvalue holds the value of the object?

Also, could someone clarify for me why lvalues (glvalues) have to be converted to rvalues (prvalues)? Is there a reason why it has to be converted, in cases such as initialization?

Comment: "when an objects value is required, rather than just it's value"? Please fix.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850536/lvalue-to-rvalue-implicit-conversion?

Comment: Are you talking about std::move