# Point of declaration in C++

Tags: c++

Why isn't the output `101` while I assigned the previous `x` to the new `x`?

```
int x = 101;
{
    int x = x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Output (garbage):

> 422634

I thought the second `x` would be initialized to `101`  but it isn't initialized.

Note: The solution in this case is `int x = ::x` but the question is *why* it happens.

Comment: I asked [about something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935722/does-initialization-entail-lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion-is-int-x-x-ub) recently...

Comment: The latest C++1y draft makes this undefined behavior as well, see [Has C++1y changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415661/has-c1y-changed-with-respect-to-the-use-of-indeterminate-values-and-undefined).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### *Point of declaration*

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete
>   declarator and before its initializer... [C++ Standard § 3.3.2/1]

Compiler completes the declaration when it knows enough about declarator.

Above code is equal to the below one:

```
int x = 101;
{
  int x;
  x = x; <------------------// Self assignment, assigns an indeterminate value.
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Because, the declaration of inner `x` completed before `=` (assignment)

```
int x = x; <--// Now, we have the new `x` which hides the older one, 
     ^        // so it assigns itself to itself
     |
     +---// Point of declaration,
         // here compiler knows everything to declare `x`.
         // then declares it.
```

On the other hand, when we declaring complex objects, the point of declaration is farther. So, the behavior is different.

For example, below code is OK

```
const int i = 2;
{
  int i[i];
         ^
         |
         +----// Point of declaration
              // compiler has to reach to "]"
              // therefore before declaring `i` as an array
              // there is just one `i`, the `i` of `const int i=2`
}
```

In above code, compiler has to know the actual size of the array to complete the declaration, so the point of declaration is `]`. Therefore the `i` within `[i]` is the outer `i` because declaration of the `i` of `int i[...` isn't completed yet. Thus, it declares an array with `2` elements (`int i[2];`).

Also, this example shows the point of declaration for an enumerator

```
const int x = 12;
{
  enum { x = x };
               ^
               |
               +---// Point of declaration
                   // compiler has to reach to "}" then
                   // there is just one `x`, the `x` of `const int x=12`

}
```

The enumerator `x` is initialized with the value of the constant `x`, namely `12`.

Comment: Maybe we can add that the declaration is also complete when using the c++11 `auto` keyword, and furthermore it's an error to do `auto x = x`

Comment: @Geoffroy: I've made a question about `auto x=x;` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19133452/952747)

Comment: What would be the point of declaration, when using direct initializers? (e.g. int x(x)). The Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler (MSVC 2017) seems to put the point of declaration at the closing parens.

Comment: @deepmax If you are right, then GCC has an issue, because "int i(i)" compiles without any global "i" defined. (only warning, that i is uninitialized)

Comment: @Tom: Umm, let me change my opinion, If `int i(i);` is like `int i = i;` then then MSVC is wrong. Isn't it?

Comment: @deepmax `int i(i);` is like `int i = i;` in GCC. In MSVC `int i(i);` does not compile without global `i` defined.

Answer (score 9):

There's another way to do it.

```
#include <iostream>
int x = 101;
int main()
{
  int x = ::x;
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
  std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Right, but the question is asking about _why_, not _how to solve it_.

Comment: @MM The question is *"Why is the output not 101 if I assigned the previous x to the new x?"* - this answer can be seen as answering the question in the sense of: *"because you haven't qualified the name as follows:"*. It's a worthwhile answer IMO, along with your one (which is also a great answer).

Answer (score 0):

variable scope 
In front of x will be overwritten.
int x = x;
This one there are two processes.
One: int x;(define variable x and allocate memory and specify the initial value : x = 0);
this moment , the front x will be hidden.
Two: x = x;(Do not find the value x);