# How is void *a = &a legal?

Tags: c++

Consider the following C++ code:

```
void* a = &a;
```

Why doesn't the compiler complain for using an undeclared identifier?

Also, what does the compiler consider the variable `a` to be? Is it a pointer to a void object or is it a pointer to a `void*` pointer?

Comment: [Point of Declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/179x7xb9.aspx)

Comment: [Point of Declaration in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15746272/952747)

Comment: Should mention why you'd want to do this - to get a pointer to the top of the stack (from which you can fiddle with all sorts of things).

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The scope of declaration of variables in C++ can be pretty surprising:

```
void* a =               &a;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          a declared as `void*` from here on
```

Therefore, `&a` is `void**` but since any pointer type is implicitly convertible to `void*`...

Comment: How would I assign a useful object to this?

Comment: @user2681063 `a = &userfulObject`?

Comment: @MarkGarcia: Note that `void *a = a;` would be UB if declared locally, otherwise it is fine at namespace scope.

Comment: Is this also applicable in C?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: I would believe it is, yes.

Comment: Ok, now the question becomes: **WHY** is this allowed? I understand scoping, but I don't understand why you would want to do `int a; void *a = &a`?

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson: there is no talk of `int a;` in my demonstration so I am not sure where you are going on... regardless, if we simply stick to the example, I would say it is allowed because there is no reason **not to** and it would be extra effort to forbid it.

Comment: A spec citation would be really nice here.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I can see 3 points for citation (declaration, address of uninitialized variable and conversion to `void*`), but unfortunately finding either in the specs is always an uphill battle...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Doesn't mean it can't be done. I always use the ToC

Answer (score 30):

It is equivalent to

```
void* a;
a = &a;
```

Therefore, `a` has been declared. So `a` gets the address of `a` written in `a`. So it is a pointer to a void pointer. (You did not define any objects yet.)

Comment: Technically, you did define one object. `a` itself is a object. (Not all objects have user-defined types in C++)

Comment: @MSalters what is this 'object' you speak of? :D

Comment: @Gusdor We can only assume what lies beyond the void of the event horizon.

Comment: They are called differently, however the "effect" is the same in this case

Comment: They are not equivalent in general, but in _this_ scenario they are.

Answer (score 7):

In `void* a`, `a` is declared as a pointer not to a `void` type but to "any" type (special case).  An address (position in memory) is assigned to `a`, as to any other variable being declared, of course.

After that, expression `&a` is evaluated to initialize the variable (also `a`, but this is not relevant) just declared.  The type of `&a` is "pointer to pointer to any type", which is a special case of "pointer to any type", fully compatible with the type of `a`.  Ergo, no compiler message.

Corollary:  do not use `void*` if you want strong type checking.  *Anything* can be converted to it.  Just the opposite in the reverse direction, except for `void*` itself (it would be an unnecessary exception that a type was incompatible with itself).

Also, AFAIR this really comes from C.