# Assigning an int's own address to its value

Tags: c++, c

Is the following code undefined behavior, implementation defined or defined by the standard?
I couldn't find any reference regarding assigning an integer to its own address.

```
volatile int x = (int)&x;
```

This code gets translated to:

```
lea         eax,[ebp-4]  
mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],eax
```

Comment: I think this boils down to how casting addresses to integers is handled. The fact that it's stored in the integer itself, I think, is of no consequence.

Comment: The value of `x` will be implementation defined, as long as `int` is at least as wide as `int *`; just like every other time you use `reinterpret_cast` to go from a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: I would say it is implementation defined.  On some platforms, an `int` may not be able to hold the value of the pointer (address).  For example, a 16-bit word system with 24-bit addressing.

Comment: The famous C/C++ standard?

Comment: Also highly depends on the platform.  There may not be accessible memory at all locations.

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153065/converting-a-pointer-into-an-integer

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567905/c-is-it-safe-to-cast-pointer-to-int-and-later-back-to-pointer-again

Comment: Just about the wording in the title vs sample code shown, shouldn't this be: _'Assigning an int's own address to it's value'_?

Comment: @DieterLücking This is not a duplicate. I'm asking about the behavior of the compiler when assigning to a local integers it's own address whilst the question your'e pointing at deals with providing address as an argument to a function

Comment: It's interesting to note that obviously the compiler didn't anticipate this and use eax as both the destination address and the value. Or is that because it's tagged volatile?

Comment: @g-makulik: Your title is much better than mine :)

Comment: @kfsone: the volatile keyword just keeps the compiler from optimizing the code away.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In C, using `x` in both the declaration and the initialization is fine:

> (C99, 6.2.1p7) "[...] Any other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator."

The result of the conversion of the pointer to the integer is implementation-defined and can be undefined behavior:

> (C99, 6.3.2.3p7) "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type."

Answer (score 11):

In C++, according to the [*point of declaration rule*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15746272/952747). It's well defined. Because before `=`, the variable `x` is declared and then `&x` is known.
Here is a tricky point, below code is *undefined behavior*:

```
int x = x;        // undefined behavior, using uninitialized variable
```

but...

```
int x = (int)&x;  // defined behavior
```

I'm talking about C++, but I believe it's valid for C too.

Answer (score 2):

In the ASM-code you show, the value of the pointer is first put into `eax`, and then the pointer is read from `eax` and put into the same location as the value of the integer was.

The only problem here is that an `int` not always is the same size as an `int*`. On my 64-bit machine, `int`s are 4 bytes and pointers are 8 bytes. If I had run your code on my box, i would get only half the pointer.