# Why printf() is printing 0 instead of 10 in following code?

Tags: c, linux, variables

If i compile and run the following code, it is printing 0 instead of 10.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int Var=10;
   {
     char Var=Var;
     printf("%d",Var);
   }
}
```

Why this is printing 0 and why not 10 ?

Comment: `=Var` already refers to `char Var`.

Comment: Now you would be like to read this: [Point of declaration in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746271/point-of-declaration-in-c#) but its a C++ link

Comment: [Point of Declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/179x7xb9.aspx)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because in local declaration

```
 char Var=Var;
```

the right occurrence of `Var` refers to the local `Var`, not the upper one. As [Alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk) commented, this is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to assign from an uninitialized variable.

So your declaration does not initialize `Var` at all, i.e. `Var` contains garbage. In your particular case, that garbage happens to be 0.

BTW, having two homonyms `Var` in the same function is really bad taste.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22954024/841108) suggests, you should compile with `gcc -Wall -Wshadow` then you'll get some warnings on your code. (also add `-g` to get debug information to be able to debug with `gdb`)

Comment: So, shouldn't it contain garbage ?

Comment: So it can print an garbage value including `0`.. right!!

Comment: +1!  Does compiler or IDE can warn about potential problem. Sorry , I am used to IntelliJ inspections.

Comment: @Basile: makes sense now.

Comment: Also it not always print `0` but anything.

Comment: @Jayan : I think user702245's answer is what you are looking for. (`-Wshadow`)

Comment: Moreover reading out the inner `Var` invokes *undefined behaviour*, as it hadn't been initialised prior to being read.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are using gcc, you would want to turn on -Wshadow (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).
This would pop up an error, at the inner variable having same name as outer. The zero is a random value. It could print any garbage in that place.

Comment: You might consider deleting your answer now, since it has become redundant after [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22953927/2235132) was edited.

Comment: That answer has a link to this answer. Is it ok to delete? I don't know, is this even the right place to ask this question?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int Var1=10;
   {
     char Var=Var1;
     printf("%d",Var);
   }
}
```