# Why we can use the declared variable in its constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, declaration

I recently ran into some weird bugs due to this kind of code.

```
vector<int> a(a);
```

Why the code above is accepted? When is this necessary? 
And how to ask the compiler to forbid this kind of usage?
Thank you.

Comment: Well, you can spot it by [the warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b945fa62ce2957a9). Anyway, when you declare a variable, it's in scope right after its declaration, which incidentally includes its initialization. As an aside, there's a [cppquiz question](http://cppquiz.org/quiz/question/119) about this.

Comment: I'd guess it's UB ...

Comment: @chris Whoah clang! Sadly, [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d13b5d834d69310a) doesn't seem to think so even with the same compiler flags.

Comment: @MarkGarcia that disappointed me to.

Comment: @MarkGarcia, That's odd. I could have sworn it did last I saw. For example, [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/034c74e2a694c17d). Oddly enough, `int i = i;` does not in either, so I'm not sure whether it's not actually UB or they just don't detect it.

Comment: @chris: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935722/does-initialization-entail-lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion-is-int-x-x-ub. In short the rhs is converted to a prvalue and since it is an uninitialized value it ub.

Comment: @JesseGood, Oh geez, it's `&*p` and `&arr[size]` all over again. Still, thanks :)

Comment: On MSVC13 the above will not compile: error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier.

Comment: @Marian, I think you mean MSVC12 (VS2013), but that's definitely wrong behaviour, as explained in the cppquiz link. `a` is available for use then for sure.

Comment: @chris: UB in most cases need not be diagnosed by the compiler. And yes, it is undefined behavior in this case, as you are reading out of an uninitialized variable (to initialize itself)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common use case for that is actually in C, not C++ (you should not use `malloc` in C++, although you can), but in this case C++ is backwards compatible:

```
mytype *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
```

By allowing the use of `p` in the initializer expression, you can pass `sizeof *p` to `malloc` ensuring that whatever the size of `mytype` is, the right size will be allocated. If you were not allowed to do `*p`, then the expression above would have to have the type `mytype` twice, and later maintenance in the code might update one of the types and fail to update the other.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the answer, I never wrote C code in such a way.

Answer (score 2):

This is an unusual construct to actually make use of, but it can be useful if a class has a constructor that takes a reference to some other object for some reason, and the caller may want to loop the object into its own initialization.

Here's a contrived example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct PrintAnAddress {
    PrintAnAddress()
        : msg_("")
        , addr_(NULL)
    { }
    PrintAnAddress( char const *msg, PrintAnAddress const &that )
        : msg_( msg )
        , addr_( &that )
    { }
    void operator()( ostream &os ) const {
        cout << msg_ << addr_ << endl;
    }
private:
    char const *msg_;
    PrintAnAddress const *addr_;
};

int main() {
    PrintAnAddress p1;
    PrintAnAddress p2( "p1:", p1 );
    PrintAnAddress p3( "self:", p3 );
    p1(cout);
    p2(cout);
    p3(cout);
}
```

When `p2` is defined, it's set up to print the address of `p1`, but when `p3` is defined, it's set up to print its own address.  If the `p3` variable were not yet in scope, it would not be possible to refer to it in order to pass it in its initialization.  (At least, not without instrumenting the class and somehow getting access to the `this` pointer.)

I'm sure there are useful and valid applications of this construct, but as I say, it's pretty unusual, so none come to my mind at the moment.