# Initialize C++ const variable with itself

Tags: c++, initialization, constants

Just now I had a bug of the following sort:

```
#include <iostream>

const int i = i;

int main(void)
{
    /* not allowed by default, but with -fpermissive */
    //const int i;
    /* allowed by default, even without -fpermissive. Seems to initialize to 0 */
    for ( int j = 0; j < i; ++j )
        std::cout << "hi";
    /* i = 0 */
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ const-init.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2
```

Because the compiler silently initialized i to 0 some loops were optimized away. The error happened because of a copy-paste error.

Is this 'feature' valid and/or documented somewhere? What is it even good for? Does it have a name?

Edit: Without -O2 g++ behaves like I would want it to behave: it issues the following error

```
const-init.cpp:8:19: warning: ‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     const int i = i;
                   ^
```

So why does the compiler assume 0 for i when using the `-O2` Flag and even deletes the whole loop because of this assumption?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152298/why-is-initialization-of-a-new-variable-by-itself-valid

Comment: There's probably much more information than you need in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415661/has-c-standard-changed-with-respect-to-the-use-of-indeterminate-values-and-und), but TL;DR: don't rely on the value of `i`. The variable `i` is in scope for its own initialization, but its value is not well-defined.

Comment: You guys are fast, after posting this question I noticed that -Wall does indeed issue a warning, but not so when using -O2. I specified this in the question

Comment: When the code causes undefined behaviour the compiler may assume anything

Comment: Why do you say that the compiler assumed that `i` is `0`?  Your observation (elimination of the loop) is equally 
consistent with `-1`, or `-999`, or `INT_MIN`.

Comment: @Voigt: I sad 0, because I didn't have the idea to test other conditions, but you are right, the loop is equally optimized away for e.g. `for ( int j=2; j>i; j--)` The only thing which won't be optimized away is: `if ( i == i ) std::cout << "At least it's equal.\n";`
It all makes sense considere the comment by M.M. That should be an answer. The current answer by ThomasG doesn't question my statement of i being 0 like Voigt did.

Comment: @mxmlnkn quite old question, but just in case you still care: I had a very similar problem and tried to find out how to get a warning also with `-O2` (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497982/how-to-make-g-generate-an-error-warning-for-int-i-i/36498051#36498051)). Seems like this problem is fixed in more recent versions of g++

Comment: @M.M I am not sure this is UB even after [DR 2026](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34276374/1708801)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its name is "undefined behaviour" and setting `i` to 0 is just one possible outcome.