# how to make g++ generate an error/warning for int i = i?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I had a hard time to find a bug in my code caused by a loop like this:

```
for (int i=i;i<5;i++){
    // ...
}
```

**I use g++ 4.7.2 with `-O2 -Wall`, but no warning/error is shown. Is there some compiler flag that also in combination with `-O2` creates a warning for such a case?**

I found several related questions:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704361/initialize-c-const-variable-with-itself) in the comments it is discussed, that g++ shows a warning with `-Wall` when there is no `-O2`. However, that question is particular because the problematic loop is optimized away with `-O2` which would explain that no warning is shown. In my case the loop is not optimized away, but still I get no warning.
Also related is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152298/why-is-initialization-of-a-new-variable-by-itself-valid) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935722/does-initialization-entail-lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion-is-int-x-x-ub). After reading those questions, I understand why c++ allows such non-sense (I like the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28152416/4117728) because it isnt nonsense at all), but I am still looking for a compiler flag that would create a warning also with `-O2`.

Comment: Upvoting question because it made me realize my gcc has the same problem and I should use a more recent one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clang compiler gives me, when compiling

```
int main()
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i=i; i<5; ++i)
        j++;
    return 0;
}
```

with `-O2 -Wall`:

```
warning_loop.cxx:4:16: warning: variable 'i' is uninitialized 
when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]
 for (int i=i; i<5; ++i)
```

The gcc (version 5.3) compiler gives a warning as well:

```
warning_loop.cxx: In function 'int main()':
warning_loop.cxx:4:16: warning: 'i' is used uninitialized in 
this function [-Wuninitialized]
 for (int i=i; i<5; ++i)
```

The usage of uninitialized values can be traced with valgrind

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes ./a.out
```

To give output:

```
==33052== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==33052== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==33052== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==33052== Command: ./a.out
==33052== 
==33052== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==33052==    at 0x100000F8C: ??? (in ./a.out)
==33052==    by 0x10022F5AC: start (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==33052==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==33052==    at 0x7FFF5FC01036: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
```

Comment: Did you try `-Wall -O2` as well ?

Comment: Yes, that does not make a difference

Comment: What does valgrind give in your case?

Comment: I am not building an executable, but an `.so` that is dynamically loaded by some framework. When I try `valgrind ./mylib.so` it shows me only one error in something that is actually not part of my code :(

Comment: well, still the same, however, as the behavior of g++ is different in more recent versions, I doubt that there is a flag for 4.7.2 that would do what I want and I guess your answer is the best I can get. Thanks for the help