# Self-referencing class

Tags: c++

I am making a tree-based data structure where there is one immutable root and each node is assigned a parent that never changes. Each node requires a reference to the parent.

I decided to use references instead of pointers, and came up with the following attempt to check if a particular node is the root:

```
#include <cstdio>

class Obj {
public:
    Obj &parent;
    Obj(Obj &parent) : parent(parent) {}
    int hasparent();
};

int Obj::hasparent()
{
    return &parent != this;
}

int main()
{
    Obj base(base);
    Obj child(base);

    printf("base.hasparent = %d\n", base.hasparent());
    printf("child.hasparent = %d\n", child.hasparent());
    printf("child.parent.hasparent = %d\n", child.parent.hasparent());
}
```

I would like your critique. Is this correct? Being unfamiliar with C++, I am actually surprised that the compiler allowed me to pass a reference to an object that I didn't construct yet. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Why don't you just set the parent to `nullptr` instead of itself?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I dismissed that after reading that [references must point to valid objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364536/is-null-reference-possible).

Comment: only problem with this approach is that tree becomes statically defined, can't be relocated.

Comment: I'm surprised that the compiler allows it, but it appears to work. You could also consider using `const` pointers.

Comment: @giusti Patrick may be proposing you make `parent` a `Obj*` instead of a `Obj &`.

Comment: @Beta  this is not against standard, so compiler can't forbid this. "&parent != this;" might be problem on some platforms where automatic relocation is possible, but those platforms themselves deviate from standard.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is nothing wrong here. Though using a refrence type as a data member makes your class unassignable and unmovable.

Comment: [Why is initialization of a new variable by itself valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152298/why-is-initialization-of-a-new-variable-by-itself-valid)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That's the approach I would take in C. But I'm studying C++ so I decided to see what I can do with references.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think, it's not the same case, because here we initialize reference. That's equal to initializing pointer with address of uninitialized variable.

Comment: @giusti issue with references is that  are immutable, once initialized.  If your target is to create object which you can't change legally then it's valid point.

Comment: @Swift That's mentioned in the accepted answer. It uses `void *p = &p;` as an example.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux alright, I need more booze.. I can't do inception that deep right now

Comment: @Swift Thanks for  the remark. In this particular structure, once a node is created, the parent will never change.

Comment: I'd have the parent point to the child using a `std::shared_ptr`, and the child point to the parent using `std::weak_ptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem with your code. If you want to hide the "weird looking initialization" of "Obj base (base)", then you could implement the default constructor to set the parent to the object itself:

```
Obj() : parent(*this) { }
```

Then you can simply initialize base like this:

```
Obj base;
```