# Is int &ref = ref; well formed

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, selfinitialization

I have learned that evaluating an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior. In particular, `int i = i;` is undefined behavior. I have read [What's the behavior of an uninitialized variable used as its own initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200465/)

But, is using a reference variable to initialize itself also undefined behavior? In particular, is `int &ref = ref;` also UB, as per the C++ standard?

```cpp
int &ref = ref; // Is this well-formed or ill-formed or UB
```

All compilers [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/T7jdTdEah) the above program (with clang giving a warning). Is this because it is undefined behavior so anything is allowed to happen, or is the program well-formed?

---

Additionally, if I were to assign some value to `ref`, will the behavior of the program change from the previous case?

```cpp
int &ref = ref;

int main()
{
    ref = 1; //does this change the behavior of the program from previous case
}
```

I noticed that for this 2nd snippet, we get a segfault.

Some references that I've read are:

[What's the behavior of an uninitialized variable used as its own initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200465/)

[Why is initialization of a new variable by itself valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152298/)

Comment: Yes, it is undefined behavior, you can not use reference without initializing it.

Comment: Most probably your program will give you SIG FAULT.

Comment: @foragerDev Can you give me a reference from the c++ standard. No it does not give seg fault.

Comment: @foragerDev No seg fault for the first snippet `int &ref = ref;` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jq96qaY4a). Also note the question is [tag:language-lawyer]

Comment: @Alan its an undefined behavior to use reference variable before you initialize it. Language does not define anything, what will your program do.  You can see this here: https://godbolt.org/z/T6Ks61ajK

Comment: There's kind-of/sort-of similar case, `struct Foo { Foo(Foo* self) { assert(self == this); } Foo(Foo const* self) { assert(self == this); };` and then the **Foo** object can check if it was created const or non-const, `Foo foo(&foo);` and `Foo const const_foo(&const_foo);`  Other than that sort of naval gazing, I'm not sure if there is a lot of use cases for self-referencing.

Comment: The committee hasn't yet come up with proper set of constraints on valid use cases of self-reference in initialization. The cases you illustrated are well-known examples of ill-formed usage; but since there are well-formed uses(e.g `QWidget::QWidget`), the line between good and evil is not clear enough to enable enforcing a generic rule.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is not defined behaviour.

[[dcl.ref]p5](https://wg21.link/dcl.ref#5.sentence-3):

> [...] A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function.

And there is no `int` object to refer to.

---

You could also say that the reference is being used outside of its lifetime.

[[basic.life]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#2):

> 3. The lifetime of a reference begins when its initialization is complete. The lifetime of a reference ends as if it were a scalar object requiring storage.
> 4. The properties ascribed to objects and references throughout this document apply for a given object or reference only during its lifetime.

So, the reference cannot be "used" to initialize itself before it is itself initialized, which is how Clang complains about this (https://godbolt.org/z/Ea4qPoWbs):

> ```
> note: use of reference outside its lifetime is not allowed in a constant expression
>     2 |     int& ref = ref;
>                        ^
> ```

Comment: Why not mention https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/453?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer That wording seems to imply `const size_t& s = sizeof(s);` should be ill-formed

Comment: @Artyer: Because `sizeof` is an unevaluated context, it is not dependent on the lifetime of any object mentioned.  In fact, it only cares about the type of the expression, and not its value or identity.  But yeah, the restriction on "the name" seems wrong.  Possibly "used" is the key, in standardese that can have a narrow meaning.