# Initializing member variable with pointer to itself

Tags: c++, initialization, undefined-behavior, pointer-to-member

I've heard that the following is valid and leaves `x` uninitialized as if it were `int x;`:

```
int x = x;
```

What about this? Is this code equivalent to the above:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int Foo::*p) : x(this->*p) { }
    int x;
};

int main() {
    Foo f(&Foo::x);
}
```

Is `f.x` still uninitialized? Do I have undefined behavior?

Comment: For `int x = x` see [Does initialization entail lvalue-to-rvalue conversion? Is `int x = x;` UB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14935722/1708801) and [Has C++ standard changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior in C++14?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++14 makes it clear that using an [indeterminate value is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801), from section `8.5` (*emphasis mine*):

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is
>   default-initialized. **When storage for an object with automatic or
>   dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate
>   value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that
>   object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced**
>   (5.17 [expr.ass]). [Note: Objects with static or thread storage
>   duration are zero-initialized, see 3.6.2 [basic.start.init]. —end
>   note] **If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the
>   behavior is undefined except in the following cases**:

The only exceptions being in the case of unsigned char. Which is probably why they changed the example section 3.3.2 from:

```
int x = 12;
{ int x = x; }
```

To:

```
unsigned char x = 12;
{ unsigned char x = x; }
```

I do not see any exceptions that would exclude your example.

`x` has an indeterminate value until it is initialized but then you access its value during the initialization which invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this code equivalent to the above:

I would think so, yes, because you are essentially doing `: x(x)`, just using a pointer to read the current value of `x` as the input value, but `x` has not been initialized yet.