# One definition rule about class member access expression

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

In N4296, 3.2 [basic.def.odr]p3:

> A variable `x` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression `ex` is odr-used by `ex` unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x` yields a constant expression that does not invoke any non-trivial functions and, if `x` is an object, `ex` is an element of the set of potential results of an expression `e`, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to `e`, or `e` is a discarded-value expression.

How to explain this paragraph? I found two explanation.

1 from here "[Trying to understand [basic.def.odr]/2 in C++14 (N4140)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997142/trying-to-understand-basic-def-odr-2-in-c14-n4140)"

> Let's split this into steps: The occurrence of a variable `x` in an expression `ex` constitutes an odr-use unless:
>
> 1. **Either** `ex` is not potentially evaluated, **or**
> 2. **All of the following must be fulfilled:**
>
>    1. *"applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x` yields a constant expression that does not invoke any non-trivial functions"* **and**
>    2. *"`ex` is an element of the set of potential results of an expression `e`"* **and either of the following holds**:
>
>       1. *"**either** the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to `e`"*
>       2. *"**or** `e` is a discarded-value expression"*

and 2 from cppreference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

> a variable `x` in a potentially-evaluated expression `ex` is odr-used unless **any** of the following is true:
>
> - applying lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x` yields a constant expression that doesn't invoke non-trivial functions
> - `x` is an object and ex is one of the potential results of a larger expression `e`, where that larger expression is either a discarded-value expression or an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion

First answer about two rules is **and**, the other is **any**. Which one is right?

Please split rules into steps to explain this code:

```
struct S { static const int x = 0; };
extern S s;// no definition of s
int i = s.x;// is s odr-used? is x odr-used?
            // gcc 5.1.0 is ok
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cppreference <strike>is</strike> was wrong; it is clear from the language in the standard (whichever version) that both subclauses must hold. I've corrected it.

In your example, `s` is not a constant expression (C++14: does not satisfy the requirements for appearing in a constant expression) so is odr-used. The second subclause does not arise.

Meanwhile, `x` is also odr-used, because although it would be possible to use `x` in a constant expression in an appropriate context (e.g. as an array bound within the definition of `S`); `x` is not one of the potential results of the enclosing expression `s.x`, which is the only enclosing expression subject to either the discarded-value transformation or the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

gcc might be OK without a definition of `s` or `x`, but there's no requirement that an implementation diagnose every odr violation.

Comment: _A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of **an object**_. `x` is an object so it is a variable.

Comment: @dyp sorry, must be a bad day. Of course, this is object vs. reference, not object of class type vs. primitive.

Comment: @stackcpp yes, that's correct - by "object" the Standard means object vs. reference, not object of class type vs. primitive.