# Clang (3.6.0) ignores warnings from included header files

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

It seems that clang is ignoring warnings which occur in included header files:

```
// what.hpp
class What {
public:
    What() {
        int x = x;
    }
};

// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "what.hpp"
int main()
{
    int y = y;
    std::cout << "y is: " << y << std::endl;
    What w;
}
```

Compiling this with g++ (4.9.2) gives:

```
$ g++ -dumpversion && g++ -Wall -Wextra main.cpp -o main
4.9.2
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
what.hpp: In constructor ‘What::What()’:
what.hpp:5:17: warning: ‘x’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     int x = x;
             ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:5:13: warning: ‘y’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
 int y = y;
```

Compiling the same thing with clang:

```
$ clang++ --version && clang++ -Wall -Wextra main.cpp -o main
Ubuntu clang version 3.6.0-2ubuntu1~trusty1 (tags/RELEASE_360/final) (based on LLVM 3.6.0)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
main.cpp:5:13: warning: variable 'y' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]
int y = y;
    ~   ^
1 warning generated.
```

I'm not sure, If I'm using clang wrong or if this is indeed a bug?
Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably that depends from the fact that `x` is completely unused (there are no references to it anywhere), so it's ignored completely by `clang`. Try to add a similar `cout` in the `What` constructor.

Comment: @MatteoItalia indeed, as I note in my answer, I found a clang bug report on this exact case and it is considered a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not `clang` bug, the warning is being suppressed because `x` is subsequently unused, the bug report I cite below explains the rationale behind this behavior.

In this specific case it is considered a clang *feature* to not to produce this warning(`Wuninitialized`) if the variable is otherwise unused, although most will probably find this surprising behavior.

We can see the rationale from the following bug report: [No uninitialized warning for self-initialization (e.g., int x = x)](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18878):

> Right, this is deliberate, and is considered to be a feature rather
>   than a bug. We suppress the warning on 'int x = x;' *only* in the case
>   where 'x' is otherwise unused.

It is mentioned in the bug report that self-intialization in this way is:

> considered the canonical way to suppress "use of uninitialized
>   variable" warnings

This does not depend on whether the code in question is included from a header, I put together a [live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7Tp7deJOz19z3JEq) that shows the warning does not show up when the code is all in one file.

Note, initializing a variable in this way:

```
int x = x;
```

is undefined behavior, for reference see:

- [Does initialization entail lvalue-to-rvalue conversion? Is `int x = x;` UB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14935722/1708801)
- [Has C++ standard changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior in C++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801)

So in general we can not have any expectations as to the result and the compiler is not obligated to issue a diagnostic although doing so can be helpful.

Comment: Sp the compiler writer decided not to warn about an obvious  case of UB and call it a feature? I probably don't have the experience to understand the usefulness but that sounds like a really dumb idea.

Comment: @MikeMB well I find it surprising but that is their rationale.

Answer (score 1):

The lines in question are syntactically correct. Neither are particularly useful lines of code - both exhibit undefined behavior - but they're legal C++ code. As such, the compiler is not obligated to issue any diagnostic.

This is just a quality of implementation issue - the compiler isn't obligated to issue warnings in this case, but it's very helpful when it does. As to why clang happens to warn only for `y` and not for `x`, whereas gcc warns for both - I am not sure. It definitely has nothing to do with included header files (you can see for yourself by just defining `What` in `main.cpp`) and likely has to do with the fact that you're printing `y` and never reading from `x` again.

But you can't *rely* on complete accuracy with these warnings. When you get them, however, they're always worth paying attention to.