# Using a variable with the same name in different spaces

Tags: c++, c, variable-declaration

This code compiles, but I have a run time error in [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio):

> Run-time check failure #3 - the variable 'x' is being used without being initialized...

```
int x = 15;
int main()
{
    int x = x;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand that behavior... in the error box when I click continue the program resumes and x has a corrupted content (like `-8556328` instead of `15`).

Why does this code work without a problem, and the int array is well declared?

```
const int x = 5;
int main()
{
     int x[x] = {1,2,3,4};
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: You tagged both C and C++. Which did you compile?

Comment: Some interesting facts: `gcc 4.8.4`, compiles and this program can be run with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` turned on. `clang 7.0.0` compiles it, and can be run as is. However if `printf("%d\n", x);` is added after `int x=x;` (I guess any actual usage of  `x`), the compiler gives the more friendly warning: `warning: variable 'x' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]`. `gcc` still compiles and runs it even with the `printf` and printed `0`. However running the program through valgrind gives `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`

Comment: @Joakim: Interesting; thanks for the results. Are GCC and Clang within their rights, i.e. is this canonically undefined behaviour?

Comment: @underscore_d - C++ doesn't require any diagnostics on uninitialized variables.  And the compiler is free to optimize away a variable altogether, especially if it is never really used after the assignment.  In fact, "undefined behavior" means that the compiler can do whatever it wishes.

Comment: Yup, I know what UB means, just wanted to check that the standard defined (or rather, omits to define) these particular cases as UB. Thanks for the info

Comment: @underscore_d - UB is entered in C++ if you read it before assigning it.  It's not UB if you just leave it indeterminate for some time (or forever - until the end of its scope).  During that time, the same stack address might be used for another variable, or...whatever.  I think that C is somewhat more specific about allowed behaviors, but it still allows a crash when you read it.

Comment: @underscore_d - Correction:  Reading uninitialized variable is not UB only in case you take the address of the variable somewhere.  _"If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined."_  When the address is taken, this rule still allows, for example, reading the variable twice and seeing different values, maybe even worse things.

Comment: See both [Does initialization entail lvalue-to-rvalue conversion? Is `int x = x;` UB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14935722/1708801) and [Has C++ standard changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior in C++14?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`x` is defined at the left of `=`.

so in `x[x]`, `[x]` refer to the global one,

whereas in `x = x;`, `x` hides the global `x` and initializes from itself -> UB.

Answer (score 35):

When you declare a new variable, its name becomes visible right here

```
int x =
//     ^- there
```

because it is at that point the variable is fully declared, and as such; its name means something. At this point in time any other (previously declared variable) in a surrounding scope will be hidden.

Answer (score 5):

There is no scope resolution operator in C, so you may not be able to use

```
int x = x;
```

in your program.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to know whether they want an answer for C or for C++. The latter does support scope resolution.

Comment: @underscore_d, yes C++ supports and C doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

please use SRO( Scope resolution operator ::) to tell compiler which x is real x in your mind. As user defined names are mangled( Names are decorated) something like this to avoid ambiguity at it's level, these are just names used by compiler that best suits it

```
int x = 15;// Real name = gui_x
int main()
{
    int x = x;// lui_x
    return 0;
}
```

In this way run-time will know which version you are using but to avoid ambiguity it expects from you to use specific names. Sometimes above problem arise where you don't know that you are using already used names. For this C++ has created SRO. 
Now in case of array x is address & not integer that stores something, that's why compiler didn't jumbled. You need to write

```
namespace abc //now all global variables are belongs to this ns abc
int x = 15;// Real name = gui_x
int main()
{
int x = abc::x;// lui_x
return 0;
}
```