# In class nested static const member variable initialization Clang vs GCC which compiler is right?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, static-members

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
  static int const i = i + 1;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << Foo::i << std::endl;
}
```

Clang version 3.7 compiles this and outputs `1`.

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8027d91d764502e4)

While GCC version 5.3 emits an error:

> *error: 'i' was not declared in this scope*

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbb375ffc625f01e)

### Q:

Which one of the two compilers conforms to the C++ standard?

Comment: `static int const i = i + 1;` makes little sense, if you want to initialize at 1, just initialize at 1.

Comment: @Shark Indeed. However this is a language lawyer question.

Comment: Normally the object [is fully defined when you reach the `=`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896140/using-a-variable-with-the-same-name-in-different-spaces). Don't know if there are any special rules for const static members. But of course it is UB to read the *value* in the initializer.

Comment: @BoPersson The read would not be undefined if possible. Since constant initialization is not performed (the initializer is not a constant expression), zero-initialization is, which happens before dynamic initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC is of course wrong to complain about the name being undeclared, since the point of declaration of `i` is [immediately after its declarator](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl#1).

However, GCC is arguably right in rejecting the snippet overall. [[class.static.data]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static.data#3):

> If a non-volatile `const` static data member is of integral or
>   enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify
>   a *brace-or-equal-initializer* **in which every *initializer-clause*
>   that is an *assignment- expression* is a constant expression (5.20).**

And for [[expr.const]/(2.7)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2) not to fail, one of its four sub bullets must apply:

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to
>
> - a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a complete non-volatile `const` object **with a preceding
>     initialization, initialized with a constant expression**, or
> - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a subobject of a string literal (2.13.5), or
> - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a non-volatile object defined with `constexpr`, or that refers to a non-mutable sub-object of such an
>     object, or
> - a non-volatile glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;

(2.7.1) is the only plausible candidate, but since `i` has not previously been initialized *using an initializer*, it doesn't apply.

Note that Clang is [completely consistent](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vbiji6NCSRhSS9IQ):

```
constexpr int i = i;
void f() {
    // constexpr int j = j; // error
    static constexpr int h = h;
}
```

It appears that it treats `i` as "properly" initialized in its initializer if it has static storage duration. I filed bug [#26858](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26858).

Answer (score 2):

A static const member initialized in-class must be initialized by a constant expression. In the initializer of `i`, `i` is not initialized by a constant expression (yet) and so is not a constant expression itself. In my view both compilers are guilty.

- clang, for accepting the program
- gcc, for giving a misleading error message

Comment: How does this answer the question. -1

Comment: @Destructor Just FYI, this answers the question very directly. Which of the compilers is wrong? — Both, for such and such reasons. If you think this is not an answer, you should flag it as such.