# Why can a variable be initialized with itself?

Tags: c++, c

I found out by accident that in C/C++ I can initialize a variable with itself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static const int foo = foo;
int main() {
    int bar = bar;
    printf("%i, %i", foo, bar);
}
```

Depending on compiler version I get different results:

Those just print "0, 0" on my machine:

- g++.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 5.3.0
- g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
- gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

This one gives an error:

- gcc.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 5.3.0

```
    foo.c:2:28: error: initializer element is not constant
         static const int foo = foo;
                          ^
```

Why does this work and what would the expected behavior be?

Comment: You probably had `-Wall -Werror` only for the last one. Show your options.

Comment: @erip, I also agree with you. I also flagged your duplicate questions. By the way, this is also a duplicate of: [Does initialization entail lvalue-to-rvalue conversion? Is `int x = x;` UB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935722/does-initialization-entail-lvalue-to-rvalue-conversion-is-int-x-x-ub)

Comment: @LogicStuff I compiled without any options. With Wall the other compilers show a warning for `int bar = bar`

Comment: Please choose one of C and C++ for your questions.

Comment: `int bar = bar;` is OK, but `int bar = bar + 1;` is not. This, because bar is uninitialized here.