# Why am I getting garbage value for the C program?

Tags: c++, c, scope, initialization, declaration

Why do I get garbage value if I compile the following C code with GCC/Clang?
Note, if I just print the value of x in inner scope I get expected result.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    {
        int x = x;
        printf("%d", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `x` in scope is `x`, not `x`. (Possibly [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14935722).)

Comment: Take away the `int x = 5;` line and nothing changes in the code. That `x` is never accessed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this declaration

```
int x = x;
```

the point of declaration of the identifier `x` is after the complete definition of the declarator that is `x` is already visible before the assignment sign `=` and hides the variable with the same name declared in the outer block scope..

And you have that `x` that is not initialized is assigned to itself. As result it has an indeterminate value.

You can imagine it the following way

```
int x;
x = x;
```

Exactly the same example exists in the C++ Standard (3.3.2 Point of declaration)

> 1 The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its
>   complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its initializer (if any),
>   except as noted below. [ Example:

```
int x = 12;
{ int x = x; }
```

> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value.
>   —end example ]

In the C Standard there is written (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

> 7 Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just
>   after the appearance of the tag in a type specifier that declares the
>   tag. Each enumeration constant has scope that begins just after the
>   appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list. **Any
>   other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of
>   its declarator.**

Pay attention to the definition of enumerators. The rule for enumerators is different.

This program is well-formed and the enumerator `x` will be initialized by the variable `x` declared in the outer scope (while the enumerator `y` will be initialized by the preceding enumerator `x`).

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int x = 10;
    {
        enum E { x = x + 1, y = x };
        std::cout << "E::x = " << x << ", E::y = " << y << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
E::x = 11, E::y = 11
x = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration `int x = 5;` is out of the scope of your second block. This means that variable `x` in the following piece of code

```
{
    int x = x;
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

is different from the outside variable `x`, declared in main. So when you try to access its value in the assignment, it gives a garbage value as it did not exist in this scope before and therefore ***it is not initialized***.