# Cannot understand this LARGE_INTEGER line

Tags: windows, scheduler

I'm looking at some code regarding scheduling with QueryPerformanceFrequency. I can't understand what's going on here. Why is the rvalue wrapped in parenthesis? A LARGE_INTEGER is a struct, so initializing would require {} instead, but totally confused by this line. QueryPerformanceFrequency returns a bool, too.

```
// Initialize the resolution of the timer
LARGE_INTEGER Timer::m_freq = (QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Timer::m_freq), Timer::m_freq);
```

The header contains a Timer struct with a private member:

```
static LARGE_INTEGER m_freq;
```

Comment: It's the comma operator. It's also being badly abused.

Comment: Wow.  Initializing a variable to be equal to itself.  I wonder if that's even legal?

Comment: The usual advice about iffy coding practices is to treat whomever is going to have to maintain your code some day as a homicidal maniac who knows where you live.  Clearly the problem here is that you don't have an address.  We don't know either.

Comment: @HarryJohnston [Does initialization entail lvalue-to-rvalue conversion? Is `int x = x;` UB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14935722/995714), but a comma introduces a sequence point so I'm not sure in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad.  Just bad as the commenters have said.

Given that QueryPerformanceFrequency should be a cheap call to make, there's little need to cache it as a global (static) variable.

Do this instead.

1. Remove the `static` declaration from the m_freq variable in the class declaration.
2. Initialize `m_freq` in the constructor of your `Timer` class.

Example:

```
Timer::Timer()
{
    BOOL result = QueryPerformanceFrequency(&m_freq);

    if (result==FALSE)
    {
        // optional - set error condition.  But it's not like
        // the original code was handling the potential error either
    }
}
```