# Why is it showing random numbers? C program to read string letters

Tags: c, string

So I have to create a program that reads the user input and shows how many times each letter appears in that string, and also how many non-letters but my code for alphabets is showing random numbers..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100

void readInput (char string[]);
void Calc(char string[], int letters[]);

void
readInput (char string[])
{
    printf ("Enter a String:\n");
    fgets (string, SIZE, stdin);

    string[strlen (string) - 1] = '\0';
}

void
Calc(char string[], int letters[])
{
    int c = 0, x;
    while (string[c] != '\0')
    {
        if (string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z')
        {
            x = string[c] - 'a';
            letters[x]++;
        }

        c++;
    }

    for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
        printf ("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n", c + 'a', letters[c]);
}

int
main ()
{
    char string[SIZE];
    int letters[26];

    readInput (string);
    Calc(string, letters);
    return 0;
}
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IGAI.png)

I'm new to strings I've googled examples but can't seem to find whats wrong with my code and no idea how I will include the non-letters part.

Comment: Is `string[strlen (string) - 1] = '\0';` for chopping off the linefeed?

Comment: Referring to "how does one make the non letters part?" from @Mohammed below: by using `isalpha`. If that returns 0 the character is a non-letter, else it is a letter. Or to make it easier to derive the array index, you can use `isupper` and `islower`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of `letters` are not *initialised*. Formally the behaviour of your program is *indeterminate*.

Sort that by writing `int letters[26] = {0};` Doing that sets all elements to zero, which is what you want in this case.

Comment: Here as well, it's a nitpick of course, but the behavior is not undefined. The result is indeterminate ;)

Comment: @Mohammed you wrote: _but now how does one make the non letters part?_ What do you mean?

Comment: @MichaelWalz so the output shows: A appears 3 times; non-letters appear 4 times;

Comment: @Mohammed if it's not between 'a' and 'z' increment the "non-letter" conter

Comment: @MichaelWalz ty again, I was trying to make another loop and all haha, just added else {special ++} and printed it :D

Answer (score 4):

`letters[]` is uniinitialized.
Solution `int letters[26]={0}`.

You are reading an uninitialized value which is indeterminate. And the results doesn't conform to as you expect it to be.

Here you want to initialize the elements with `0` denoting that you haven't seen any charcaters yet. (automatic storage duration).

A better way to overwrite the `'\n'` would be

```
string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = 0;
```

Comment: Not undefined. Just indeterminate.

Comment: `You are reading an uninitialized value which is undefined behavior.`..that's an overstatement.

Comment: `letters` is passed to a function, so it has it's address taken. Therefore, reading it isn't undefined behavior, even if it's uninitialized.

Comment: Guys.... the values them self are indeterminate. *Accessing* the values is technically speaking: **undefined behaviour**

Comment: @MrPaulch no. It's only undefined behavior if the object being read could have been declared `register`.

Comment: Just answered this on a similar topic, see there for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47431348/2371524

Comment: @FelixPalmen that is a good discussion, it boils down to just about any non-aggregate type with automatic storage could have been declared register... The only bit I take issue with is one of the final comments "writing a single member is enough to have an initialized object". It's not writing to a single member that does it, it is *initializing* a single member that causes all remaining members to be treated as if they had been declared with static storage duration (and thereby initialized to zero).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin could you move your comment over there? I'd have some questions about it, but it's clearly off-topic here ;)

Comment: Sure, glad to I'll give the standard cites as well.

Answer (score 0):

you should initialize `letters` with all 0 values