# Is this portable?

Tags: c++

```
while (int grade = (std::cin >> grade, grade)) { /**/ }
```

- The condition inside `while` declares a variable and it becomes instantly visible in the `while` scope
- The second operand of assignment evaluates the expression which contains comma operator (which guarantees order of evaluation)
- The comma's left operand yields error-status from `cin` and discards it, as a side effect, `grade` gets changed
- Comma operator returns right hand side expression, that becomes the value of the variable

Is this legit code? I'm new to C++. Can you please correct my thought process.

Comment: It is behind the [door on the right](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ilMjE1Gh3Yg/VpUAmd-6TWI/AAAAAAAAAbg/-FJ08zxN42s/s1600/WFTPM.png).  You do have to explain why the left door is closed.

Comment: If you can't easily tell, assume it isn't. Also - really, don't write this kind of code.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being closed as opinion-based. This is a question of portability/spec compliance which is quite far from an opinion question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is well-defined and behaves in the expected way from C++11 up to C++17.

Before C++11, if the input operation in `std::cin >> grade` failed, `grade` would not be written to, so the right-hand `grade` of the comma operator would use an indeterminate value, which causes undefined behavior. Since C++11 `std::cin >> grade` will set `grade` to zero on input failure, so that this won't be a concern.

In C++20, the lifetime of `grade` will only begin once initialization is complete. So using it to either write to or read from in the initializer causes undefined behavior. Prior to C++20 the lifetime of a non-aggregate, non-class object began already when suitable storage for the object was obtained.

---

Details of the standard specification aside, you should not write code like that. Don't use a variable in its own initializer (except *maybe* to take a pointer/reference to it, but never to access its value). Whether or not that will work depends on many peculiarities that are not worth thinking about in order to save one additional line of code to do the declaration in a second statement.

Comment: "the lifetime of grade will only begin once initialization is complete" is true but you can vivify a trivially copyable type via assignment or is C++20 going to change that?

Comment: @BenVoigt [\[basic.life\]/7.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-7.1) forbids *any* access to the object before the lifetime begins. So I think it wont be allowed. See also my related recent question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442521/use-of-variable-in-own-initializer).

Comment: That means you can no longer vivify an inactive union member (of trivially copyable type) by copying from a live object?  That's going to break a lot of existing code.

Comment: @BenVoigt Lifetime initiation due to assignment to union members is handled with specific rules in [\[class.union\]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#6).

Answer (score 1):

The code is legal provided that the input operation was successful. Otherwise a trap value can be used to initialize the declared variable.

Comment: Modern `operator>>(istream&, int&)` is guaranteed to zero the target if the operation fails.

Comment: @BenVoigt That is still *modern*?

Comment: @Deduplicator: It is newer than the other behavior (leaving the target untouched).