Should not trying to use the non-declared variable in this case result in a compilation error?
It was a while since I had written C++ and wanted to make a chess game as a practice to get back into it.
I wrote the following class which keeps track of the coordinates of chess pieces on the board
and makes sure the coordinates are valid. Meaning for any coordinate (x, y) x and y should be in the range [0, 7].
Here was the implementation of the coordinate class:
inline bool valid_coord(const int x, const int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || x > game_settings::square_count.first) return false;
    if (y < 0 || y > game_settings::square_count.first) return false;
    return true;
}

class Board_coord
{
public:
    Board_coord(const int x, const int y)
    {
        if (!valid_coord(x, y))
        {
            BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(std::invalid_argument(
                std::format("({},{}) is not a valid coordinate", x, y)));
        }

        x_coord = x;
        y_coord = y;
    }

    int get_x() const noexcept { return x_coord; }
    int get_y() const noexcept { return y_coord; }

    bool operator==(const Board_coord& other) const
    {
        return (x_coord == other.x_coord && y_coord == other.y_coord);
    }

    friend Board_coord operator+(const Board_coord& lhs, const Board_coord& rhs);

private:
    int x_coord;
    int y_coord;

};

Board_coord operator+(const Board_coord& lhs, const Board_coord& rhs)
{
    return Board_coord{ lhs.get_x() + rhs.get_x(), lhs.get_y() + rhs.get_y() };
}

Trying to test the code I wrote the following by accident:
Board_coord p0{ 4, 3 };
Board_coord p1{ 3, 2 };
Board_coord p2{ p0 + p2 };

What suprised me was that I was able to use p2 even before it was declared. I got no compiler warnings at all (using msvc 19.41.34123 for x64 with /W4 flag set). The result was:

Throw in function __cdecl game_logic::Board_coord::Board_coord(const
int,const int) Dynamic exception type: struct boost::wrapexcept std::exception::what: (-858993456,-858993457)
is not a valid coordinate

If I am not completely overlooking something here: Should not compilation fail when trying to use a non-declared variable in this case?

It's a curiosity of C++ that using a variable to initialise itself is syntactically valid, though obviously you should never do this in practise.

perhaps this post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442521/use-of-variable-in-own-initializer

Only use the variable you define as part of the initializer if the variable is unevaluated, like size_t foo = sizeof foo; or similar is fine.

I get a compiler error, because I have -Wuninitialized and -Wuninitialized-const-reference enabled, and -Werror.  I suggest you at least enable compiler warnings, so the compiler can warn you about suspicious code.  It's like having a linter built into the compiler.

You could have shown the problem with three lines of code. Board_coord has nothing to do with it. int would do the same thing.
