# Initialization of Objects with Static Storage Duration in C vs C++

Tags: c++, c, initialization, definition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does main return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309042/what-does-main-return)

For example, the following code compiles without any warning:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = i + 1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    fprintf (stderr, "%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

I think this is illegal in syntax, because `i` is used before it's declared, is it right?

And in my opinion, the appearance of `int i = i + 1;` is surely a bug, why doesn't the compiler warn about it? I use gcc 4.5.1.

Comment: It's undefined behavior for sure...

Comment: I imagine if it does anything at all, then it sets aside memory for i, and then in the assignment it uses whatever value was stored in that part of memory (so the resulting value stored in i will be unpredictable).

Comment: Your code *doesn't* compile. gcc gives the error `initializer element is not constant`.

Comment: Then cite the standard. I don’t think that it’s necessarily undefined. It could equally well be illegal.

Comment: @Konrad : It is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Prasoon Only in C++; good to know. But without a reference to the standard this speculative answer is completely useless.

Comment: @Konrad : Check out my answer. I think the behaviour is well defined as per §3.6.2/1 (I was mistaken earlier)

Comment: In `C++`, I think, it is better form to use `#include <cstdio>` ... and maybe even `cout` and friends instead of `fprintf`

Comment: @Praason I have. *Before* writing the original comment. Your answer is good. It doesn’t vindicate this answer though.

Comment: @Konrad : I have edited my answer. I was mistaken earlier.

Comment: **This is a dupe**. Link to [original question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309042/what-does-main-return). Voted to close.

Comment: @Prasoon: according to what I read below, the answers are different for C or C++. The "original question" didn't address the C issue.

Comment: @pmg : According to @fool his code gets compiled which implies it to be C++ code.

Comment: hehe: questions tagged with both `C` and `C++` probably should have none of those tags in the first place :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(notice: I'm referring to the current C++ standard)

I'm not really sure about this, but, if my interpretation of the standard is correct, the code should be fine and not UB.

The first initialization of that variable is the *zero-initialization* of objects with static storage duration that happens *before any other
initialization takes place* (§3.6.2 ¶1).

So, first of all `i` is set to zero.

Then, *dynamic initialization* (i.e. non-zero and non-constant initialization) takes place, so it uses the current value of `i` (0) to actually initialize it again. At the end it should evaluate to 1.

This seems confirmed by §8.5 ¶6, that explicitly says:

> The memory occupied by any object of static storage duration shall be zero-initialized at program startup before any other initialization takes place. ***[Note: in some cases, additional initialization is done later. ]***

(If you find some flaw in the analysis please just tell me in the comments and I'll be glad to correct/delete the answer, it's slippery floor and I'm conscious of it :) )

Comment: section `[basic.scope.pdecl]` is also key... I agree it's well-defined.

Answer (score 5):

In C++ it is syntactically correct. In C you can initialize a global variable only with a constant. So your code would not compile in C.

In C this is legal BTW

```
int main()
{
   int i = i+1;
}
```

3.3.1/1  Point of declaration

> The point of declaration for a name is **immediately after its complete declarator** and before its initializer (if any).

The behaviour is well defined as per `§3.6.2/1` which says:

> "Objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place."

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav:: Are you sure the code of the Questioner is Undefined?"
*Objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.*"

Comment: @Acme : I am sorry. I thought you meant well defined. It is well defined.

Comment: @Acme : I edited my answer 3 minutes before you added your comment.

Comment: Could someone explain why this answer is downvoted?

Comment: In your snippet, the behaviour is undefined because the `i` variable has automatic storage, not static storage, so it pretty much does whatever the C compiler wants. If the definition was made outside of main, it would have been well defined.

Answer (score 1):

The code is illegal in C.

`initializer element is not constant`

**C99 -- 6.7.8 Initialization**

*All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be
constant expressions or string literals.*

The is valid in C++.

C++ Standard States in **3.6.2 Initialization of non-local objects**:

*Objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.*

Comment: This is what I'd expect from the initialization at global scope.  Is the same true inside a function?

Comment: @ André Caron :: Then it would be undefined behavior since variables with storage class `auto` are not initialized to any value by default.

Comment: Your post doesn't answer why the code snippet does not give any error in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not legal C.

If your compiler compiles it without a diagnostic,
**your compiler is not a C compiler**

You must use constants to initialize a variable.

In your code, the initializer expression ( `i + 1` ) is not a constant.

This violates 6.7.8/4:

> All the expressions in an initializer [...] shall be constant expressions or string literals.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a value to variable using another variable outside any function. The statement `i + 1;` is evaluated during runtime, while `int i = i + 1;` is outside any function so it needs to be evaluated in compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Whether its really syntactically illegal I'm not sure (it would definitly be valid inside the method). However, as you suggest, the is a semantic problem and the compiler should issue a warning as `i` was used without initialization. IMO the C/C++ compiler does not generally warn of such thing however (Java for instance would give an error), though you might turn on such warning by adding `-Wall` parameter to gcc.

Comment: There are no warnings, because there is nothing to warn about. If you are compiling the code as C++, it is well defined. If you are compiling the code as C, the compiler issues an error, because the construct is illegal in C.

Answer (score 0):

Since a compiler takes statements and emits low-level code for the CPU to use, you have to split apart what is really happening here.  It would go something like this:

1. Create a memory slot for "i".
2. Initialize the memory to zero (normal default behavior).
3. Read the value of "i" (which is zero).
4. Add 1.
5. Store it in "i".

Answer (score 0):

I won't repeat the same things: it is undefined behavior, you should not do it... but provide a use case (which is a common idiom) that shows why it is sometimes interesting to allow the use of the variable there (in C):

```
int * p = malloc( 10 * sizeof *p );
```

If usage of `p` in the right hand side was disallowed that would be a compiler error. You can circumvent it by explicitly stating the type in the rhs:

```
int * p = malloc( 10 * sizeof(int) );
```

But that is prone to subtle errors if at a later time the type is changed, as the compiler will not detect this case:

```
double * p = malloc( 10 * sizeof(int) ); // will compile and probably cause havoc later
```

Now, in C++ I can only assume that it is there for backwards compatibility. Note also, that some compilers will be able to detect that invalid use and trigger a warning from the more general group of *uninitialized use of variable*:

```
int i = i + 1;
//      ^  uninitialized read
```

There are other situations, however, in C++ where you can pass a reference/pointer to uninitialized objects and it is perfectly fine. Consider:

```
template <typename T>
struct NullObjectPattern { // intentionally out of order:
   T* ptr;
   T null;
   NullObjectPattern() : ptr( &null ), null() {}

   T& operator*() { return *ptr; }
   T* operator->() { return ptr; }
};
```

While `null` has not yet been initialized, using it in an expression that only takes it's address (but does not dereference it) is well defined: the memory location exists, it has been allocated and is present. The object itself has not been initialized, and as such dereferencing it will cause UB, but the fact that an uninitialized object is used in an expression does not mean that the code is actually wrong.

Comment: The behaviour is well defined in C++.

Answer (score 0):

To address your question about "`i` is used before it's declared, right?"

Not in C++.  `[basic.scope.pdecl]` says

> The *point of declaration* for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its *initializer* (if any), except as noted below. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> int  x  =  12;
> {  int  x  =  x;  }
> ```
>
> Here the second `x` is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value.  — *end example* ]