# Where in the C++ Standard can I find support for invoking a function in global scope?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the snippet below:

```
#include <iostream>
int f(int i) {
    return ++i;
}
int i = f(i);

int main() {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Where in the C++ Standard can I find support for the initialization of the global variable `i` above?

Comment: What do you mean by support?

Comment: @Borgleader Some statement supporting the call of a function in global scope

Comment: C++11 8.5 [dcl.init]

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, I ran this code on my compiler and got output as 1. If its supposed to get undefined behavior, then why did I get so...????

Comment: @Angew Could you be more precise? I didn't find anything in 8.5 about this.

Comment: People are usually more willing to helpful if you explain what research you did before posting your question. Especially since you are using the language-lawyer tag.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, but when I changed `++i` to `i`, I got output 0. It seems `i` is getting the value 0 by default, I wonder how...???

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I searched the Standard for "function call" and apparently  didn't find anything that would give support to the declaration above.

Comment: @ArunA.S [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474349/initialization-of-objects-with-static-storage-duration-in-c-vs-c) seems related to what you are asking

Comment: @Yakk I'm asking the question because I don't think this is UB of course.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It's not UB. `i` has been statically initialised to zero before calling `f(i)` during dynamic initialisation.

Comment: Now, one thing I'm not clear on: there are clauses that imply that values lacking an initializer with static or thread scope are zero-initialized.  But `i` has an initializer.  I am uncertain if "before the initializer runs" we get zero-initialization.  Or, on preview, what @MikeSeymour said.

Comment: @Yakk Yes they are. 3.6.2/2: "Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5)
before any other initialization takes place."

Comment: @MikeSeymour I see. it makes a difference, if that code appears at global scope or within a function.

Comment: @François Moisan, thanks a lot. I understood the answer on your link much better than the other ones provided.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Indeed, but this code can't appear in a function since it contains two function definitions. It's a non-local variable, initialised both statically and dynamically as described in [basic.start.init].

Comment: @Ayrosa so, you understand that the tricky part is your use of `i` in the expression to determine `i`, not the call of `f`?  Where you intending to ask about calling a function in global scope, or about using the value of a global variable in an expression to determine the initial value of the global variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initialisation of non-local variables is described in the chapter titled "Initialization of non-local variables", [basic.start.init]. In C++11, that's 3.6.2.

Initialising using `=`, the initialiser can be a braced list, or any assignment expression, including a function call, as specified in [dcl.init] (C++11 8.5).

This has static storage duration, so it's first zero-initialised during static initialisation per 3.6.2/2:

> Variables with static storage duration [...] shall be zero-initialized 
>   before any other initialization takes place.

It is then initialised from its initialiser during dynamic initialisation, since it doesn't meet the criteria for constant initialisation (since the initialiser isn't a constant expression). That passes the statically initialised zero value to the function, which increments it and returns 1. That value of 1 is used to complete the initialisation.

Comment: Now that I have the answer it seems so obvious! Thanks anyway (+1).