# Storage Duration and Member Initialization of a Struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, member, storage-duration

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    // Some Other Code
    int x;
};

A a1;

int main(){
    A a2;
    cout << "a1.x = " << a1.x << endl;
    cout << "a2.x = " << a2.x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

C++14 Standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2014) Section 8.5, Paragraph 12:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized. When storage for an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an *indeterminate value*, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced (5.17). [ Note: Objects with static or thread storage duration are zero-initialized, see 3.6.2. - end note ]

So does `a1` have Static Storage Duration and does `a2` have Automatic Storage Duration? The definition of `Struct A` is at global namespace, as well as `a1` declaration, while `a2` declaration is at block scope (inside the `main()` function).

Also, Section 3.6.2 says:

Paragraph 1:

> Non-local variables with static storage duration are initialized
>   as a consequence of program initiation.

Paragraph 2:

> Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.

Besides, with gcc 5.4.0 I get a warning (`warning: 'a2.A::x' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`) and a random value, but with clang 3.8.0 the output is always `a2.x = 0` (zero can also be an indeterminate value). I also made other more complex experiments, with nested `struct`s and default initializations placed in `// Some Other Code`. Sometimes I get random values and other times (not a negligible number of) I get a zero.

- What is the Storage Duration of Struct `A`? And that of objects `a1` and `a2`? And that of variables `a1.x` and `a2.x`?
- Shoud `a1.x` and `a2.x` be zero-initialized? Or are they indeterminate values?
- Do the same rules apply to `class` and `union`?
- Does it make any difference the code in `// Some Other Code`? For example, if a class T "has non-static members with default initializers" (like in `struct A { int b = 1; int x; };`) then the default constructor can not be trivial (i.e. can not perform no action).  Would that non-trivial constructor also initialize `x`? [Trivial Default Constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor.)

Interesting links:

[C++ Structure Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516657/c-structure-initialization)

[Initializing default values in a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782103/initializing-default-values-in-a-struct)

[Are members of a C++ struct initialized to 0 by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069621/are-members-of-a-c-struct-initialized-to-0-by-default)

[Default initialization of POD types in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212261/default-initialization-of-pod-types-in-c)

[Initialization of Objects with Static Storage Duration in C vs C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474349/initialization-of-objects-with-static-storage-duration-in-c-vs-c)

[C and C++ : Partial initialization of automatic structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828294/c-and-c-partial-initialization-of-automatic-structure)

[How to initialize structures to all-elements-zero-or-null](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~chris/random/initialise.html)

Comment: a1 is default-initialized, a2 is not.

Comment: I answered your questions except the last one, as I find it unclear. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo You are right, I'm sorry, that point was not clearly explained, I just edited it. My question was if a non-trivial constructor would also initialize (¿zero-initialize?) the remaining members of the struct that have not default initializers. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So does a1 have Static Storage Duration and does a2 have Automatic Storage Duration?
>
> The definition of Struct `A` is at global namespace ...

This is irrelevant.

> ... is at global namespace, as well as `a1` declaration

`a1` has static storage duration and it is zero-initialized.

> while `a2` declaration is at block scope

`a2` is a non-static block local variable. It has automatic storage duration and it is default initialized. It has an indeterminate value.

---

> What is the Storage Duration of Struct `A`?

Types do not have storage duration. Objects do.

> ... And that of objects `a1` and `a2`?

See above.

> .. And that of variables `a1.x` and `a2.x`?

Subobjects, including non static data members, inherit the lifetime of their superobject.

> ... Shoud `a1.x` and `a2.x` be zero-initialized? Or are they indeterminate values?

`a1` is zero initialized. This includes its subobjects. `a2` is not. This includes its subobjects.

> Do the same rules apply to class and union?

Same set of rules apply to objects of union and non-union classes as well as non class types when it comes to storage classes. There are differences in what default initialization means for different types.

> Does it make any difference the code in // Some Other Code? For example, if a constructor of class T "has non-static members with default initializers" then the default constructor can not be trivial (i.e. perform no action).

A non-trivial default constructor generated by the compiler default initializes the members that have no default initializers.

Comment: Regarding your last answer: Do you mean that a non trivial default constructor (compiler-generated) would initialize `x` to some value? Or are you referring to a non trivial user-defined constructor that explicitly initializes `x` in the code? I would understand obviously the latter, but not the former. Thanks.

Comment: @JL actually, I was wrong. Non trivial default constructor doesn't necessarily value initialize all members. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the Storage Duration of Struct A?

This question does not make sense, the storage depends on how `A` is used.

---

> And that of objects a1 and a2?

`a1` has static storage. [See this question for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281925/what-is-default-storage-class-for-global-variables)

`a2` has automatic storage.

---

> And that of variables  a1.x and a2.x?

They are stored the same way as their parent `A` instance.

---

> Do the same rules apply to class and union?

Yes.